# varioref hyperlinks go outside the text boundary

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, line-breaking, varioref

I'm using the `varioref` package to get descriptive references. When used with the `hyperref` package, the links will often go outside of the text boundary, as demonstrated in the MWE below.

If I set `breaklinks=true` in the `hyperref` package, then the link will break across lines (good), but at the expense of the link not working (bad).

Is there a way to fix this? In the context of this example, I would almost prefer, 'on the preceding page', to be regular text, and not part of the link.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[left=6cm,right=1cm,showframe=true]{geometry}               
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{cc}
  1 & 2
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{We're going to link to this table}
 \label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}

\clearpage

Some text to fill in the space. This should emulate the problem- in Table \vref{tab:mytable}

\end{document}
```

EDIT
Here's the relevant info from `listfiles`

```
varioref.sty    2011/07/27 v1.4z package for extended references (FMi)
hyperref.sty    2011/08/19 v6.82h Hypertext links for LaTeX
```

Following the comments, yes I'm using the `latex->dvips->pstopdf` route.

Comment: Your example works fine for me (line break within "on the preceding page", correct link to the top of the table).

Comment: Using your MWE, the text doesn't go into the margin for me. "preceding" is the last word on the line, then "page" on the next line. If I add some more letters, it will break the line before "preceding", still nothing going outside the text boundary. I'm using an updated version of TeXlive 2011. (Edit: Damn, too late.)

Comment: Same here. What versions of `hyperref` and `varioref` are you using? To find out, add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass{report}` and check the `.log` file after you've compiled.

Comment: I've posted my output here; I'm using TeXlive 2011, and necessarily have to use `latex->dvips->pstopdf` as the actual document uses `pstricks`

Comment: With `\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref}` the typesetting is correct. There are various ways to use **pstricks** with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Oh, ok- I always thought they wouldn't play nicely together. Is there a resource you'd recommend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably typesetting with the `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` cycle; either use `pdflatex` or add the `breaklinks` options for **hyperref**.

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: You're correct. I can't use `pdflatex` as the actual document uses `pstricks`- I've updated the question too.

Comment: See [question 8413:how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex) for using PSTricks with pdflatex.

Comment: Just for interest, I've since found that loading the `cleveref` package stops the description ('on the preceding page') from being a hyperlink, and works in the `dvips->ps2pdf` routine.

Comment: I use `pdflatex` (three iterations). `breaklinks` breaks links in both ways.

Comment: @Raphael The **breaklinks** package does nothing with `pdflatex`.

Comment: But it does; it makes links break lines (which they don't if I use `pdflatex` without the extra option) but it also makes them link to wrong places in the pdf.

Comment: @Raphael Sorry: I misunderstood; you're talking about the `breaklinks` option, I about the **breakurl** package (that's not breaklinks).

Comment: in my case I had to use `\sloppy`, as `breaklinks` was not working... -- credits to: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4022