# How to use PSTricks with PDF Texify in WinEdt?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, winedt, texify

The page [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex) explains a workaround that allows to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX. As far as I understand it, it allows you to include a mix of eps and pdf figures in a TeX document and to compile the document with pdfLaTeX. Along similar lines, I was wondering if there is any way to get PSTricks to work with PDFTeXify in WinEdt?

Comment: You must use texify in the following way:
`texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--enable-write18`
If you are using TeXLive use:
`texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--shell-escape`

Answer (score 2):

texify (or pdftexify) is merely a program that will run (pdf)latex (and, if necessary, bibtex, makeindex, and what not) for however many times it takes to get all cross-references, citations, index commands, etc sorted out and resolved properly. Hence, as long as you've set your pdflatex program to run properly with pstricks, e.g., by specifying `pdflatex -shell-escape`, you shouldn't encounter any problems with pdftexify.

Comment: @Marco @Mico Thanks to both for the answers. I had already sorted out pdflatex and that ran fine (in WinEdt: by adding `-shell-escape` before `"%N%T"` in the parameters box in Options > Execution modes > PDFLatex) but PDFTexify still did not work. However, Marco's suggestion seems to have done the trick: in Options > Execution modes > PDFTexify I added `--tex-option=--enable-write18` after `--pdf` in the switches box and now PDFTexify seems to work with PSTricks. I did a quick check and I was able to compile a document that contained both eps and pdf figures with just PDFTexify. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it works but it takes only pdf figures as input, not eps figures.

Comment: Apologies for adding to this, especially if this is common knowledge, but with `\usepackage{epstopdf}` in the preamble it is possible to include a mix of pdf and eps figures (epstopdf converts any eps files it encounters into pdfs on the spot) and run PDFTexify as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

try `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and then it should work with including eps images whith the option `-shell-escape`. And then there is no need for the package `epstopdf`