# TeXworks with XeLaTeX + MakeIndex + BiBTeX + shell escape?

Tags: bibtex, xetex, pdf, texworks, shell-escape

I have tried following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34489/7356), but it gives me:

> xelatex.exe: Invalid command-line option
>
> xelatex.exe: Data: unknown option

Shell-escape is required for [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted), and is enabled for XeLaTeX using `-enable-write18`.

What I write in LaTeX include articles with BiBTeX references. Here is the usual format I take:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@phdthesis{michael_power_1991,
    title = {The Power of Two Choices in Randomized Load Balancing},
    url = {http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/mythesis.pdf},
    school = {Harvard},
    author = {Michael David Mitzenmacher},
    year = {1991}
}
}
\end{filecontents*}
```

…

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

#### How do I add PDF rendering support for these typeset requirements within TeXworks?

Answer (score 1):

`latexmk` has a switch called `-shell-escape` that should do what you want. It takes care of `makeindex` and `bibtex` anyway.

so this should work

```
Name: xelatexmk
Program: latexmk

Arguments: -xelatex
           -shell-escape
           -e
           $synctexoption %O %S/
           $fullname
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, got this error when trying to run it: http://pastebin.com/8KzsfE9V (FYI: I removed all comments in my file just to be sure), I'm guessing it has something to do with: `$synctexoption %O %S/`…

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are using, but the command `XeLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX` in TeXworks (at least my configuration) actually calls `texify` instead of `miktex-pdftex`, so the option needs just a small addition.

Based on this:
[How to use PSTricks with PDF Texify in WinEdt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27593/how-to-use-pstricks-with-pdf-texify-in-winedt#comment54118_27624)

Add the desired option as following:

```
--tex-option=--enable-write18
```