# How to get DVI files vs PDF files when using pstricks, aquamacs, and mactex

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, shell-escape, aquamacs

My setup is generating DVI output vs PDF when using pstricks with Aquamacs 2.3a and MacTex 2011

Simple latex files will create pdf files as expected from inside aquamacs and auto view in skim.  When using .tex files with PS graphics, the only file that gets generated is DVI.  Via command line the file correctly converts to PDF with dvipdf.

A just previous setup with same .tex file was auto generating PDF's fine by setting the --shell-escape in the latex customization in Aquamacs.  Both Tex Live (MacTex) and Aquamacs were updated, but I suspect issue with Aquamacs settings.

What are the changes to Aquamacs to get back to automatically working scenario.

Old (working) from previous setup was

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) (format=pdflatex 2010.7.21)  18 SEP 2011 10:08
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input test.tex
```

New settings that will only produce DVI

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) (format=latex 2011.7.3)  7 OCT 2011 09:44
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
 Source specials enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
\pdfoutput=0  \input test.tex
```

Comment: Does this post help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex

Comment: run the document with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. Then you do not need the "shell-escape" option.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Command** menu, choose **TeXing Options** and uncheck **Generate PDF**; the keyboard combination is

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>