# PSTricks picture not compiling with pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex)

What is wrong with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,0)(2.5,1)
    \psdots(0,0)(2,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to compile it with `pdflatex`, and getting following error:

```
     ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.6     \psdots(
             0,0)(2,0)(1,1)
?
```

Comment: run the document with `xelatex` and look also at http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717671/pdflatex-giving-error?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the option `[pdf]` to `\usepackage{pstricks}` for it to work with `pdflatex`. This would make your code read as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,0)(2.5,1)
    \psdots(0,0)(2,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need to use shell escape with pdflatex for it work. Thus, issue

```
pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex
```

to compile.