# Draw a curve in latex using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I would like to draw a curve in latex but when I put this code

```
\psset{algebraic=true}
\pspicture(-2,-0.5)(2,2)

\psline{<->}(-2,0)(2,0)
\psline{->}(0,-0.5)(0,2)
\psplot{-1.5}{1}{x*x+x}

\endpspicture
```

theses errors appear

```
! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps \psline(
! Undefined control sequence.\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@\fi \space \psline(
! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps \psline
```

Please if someone can help me because i didn't understand why this error appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{xcolor} %les couleurs 
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.4,1} 
\usepackage{layout} 
\usepackage[top=2 cm, bottom=2 cm, left=2 cm, right=2 cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 
\usepackage{pst-eucl} 

\begin{document} 
\psset{algebraic=true} 
\pspicture(-2,-0.5)(2,2) 
\psline{<->}(-2,0)(2,0) 
\psline{->}(0,-0.5)(0,2) 
\psplot{-1.5}{1}{x*x+x} 
\endpspicture 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The main problem with your MWE was the line

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
```

which, when using `PSTricks` will cause some problems (unless you use [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex))

Note also that there's no need to load the `color` AND `xcolor` package- only load the `xcolor` package in the future.

I've stripped your code down to the following, which works either with `xelatex` or with the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` routine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 

\begin{document} 
\psset{algebraic=true} 
\pspicture(-2,-0.5)(2,2) 
\psline{<->}(-2,0)(2,0) 
\psline{->}(0,-0.5)(0,2) 
\psplot{-1.5}{1}{x*x+x} 
\endpspicture 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

When using PStricks with PDF output, you need to either

1. Compile with `latex` and then run `dvi2pdf`.
2. Compile with `xelatex`.
3. Compile with `pdflatex` with `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`.

In the first two cases, you need to remove the `pdftex` option from `\usepackage{graphicx}`, and in the third case, it is still recommended to omit the option.

Alternatively, you could

4. Use `pgfplots`, which works natively with `pdflatex`. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, enlargelimits=true, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
\addplot [domain=-1.5:1, thick] {x^2+x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will give you

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answers please i have an anathor question i would like to make a curve that i input its data

Comment: @boutheina: You should ask a new question for that.

Comment: @ Jake: i can't publish my question that is:good afternoon, I would like to draw a curve in latex with my own data so how i can make that please? this error appear It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: @boutheina: You'll need to add more information to your question: What compiler do you use (`pdflatex`, `latex`, `xelatex`)? What plotting package do you want to use (`PStricks`, `pgfplots`)? In what form do you want to provide the plot data (a text file of comma separated values, coordinates you'll enter into the `.tex` file)?

Comment: i change my questio to :good afternoon,

 I would like to draw a curve in latex with my own data so how i can make that please?

 i use the compiler pdflatex and i use plotting package pgfplots and I don't know what is the best form to provide this?  but the same error still

Comment: @boutheina: Hm, don't know why the system doesn't accept your answer. But really, that question kind of *is* low quality: It is expected that you have done some research of your own before posting a question. In this case, simply looking at page 16 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) would already answer your question.

Comment: :thank you but when i publish this question i want that you give me some exemples and some advices concerning houw i can do that.

Comment: @boutheina: But there are so many examples in the manual, and on this site. Just search for `pgfplots` and `data` on this site and you'll find lots. If you're looking for concrete advice, add that to your question. Also, you should pay attention to correct orthography (capitalising "I", for example), I believe that may trigger the "low quality" error as well.

Comment: in your previous comment you have said that I can use pgfplots manual  but this link doesn't work please do you have an another version please I need that.

Comment: @boutheina: That's strange, it works fine for me (it links to a PDF document). Try http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf

Comment: who can explain to me what these two instructions means because when I put this an error appear:    \addplot[color=blue,mark=*]
table[x=Cost,y=Error] {pgfplots.testtable};

Comment: @boutheina: Now *this* is an opportunity to ask a good question: Please include a minimal example document (starting from `\documentclass`), a sample of your `pgfplots.testtable` datafile, and the error message you get.

Comment: ok I will do this tomorrow because it is late now but I also want to understand what mens this because I don't know: \addplot[color=blue,mark=*]
table[x=Cost,y=Error] {pgfplots.testtable};

Comment: @boutheina: It's one instruction: `\addplot table {<data source>};` with some optional arguments. Please, take a look at p. 22 of the manual (for the `\addplot` command in general) and p. 26 (for the `table` input).

Answer (score 2):

Plotting a curve to which you supply your own data points using [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) is possible using [`pst-plot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot). You can either input the data directly in your `.tex` file, or read it from an external file. Here's a small example, taken from the [`pst-plot` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/pst-plot-doc.pdf) (see section **2 Plotting data records**, p 5-6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
  \psset{xunit=.2cm,yunit=1.5cm}
  \savedata{\mydata}[
    {{0, 0}, {1., 0.946083}, {2., 1.60541}, {3., 1.84865}, {4., 1.7582},
    {5., 1.54993}, {6., 1.42469}, {7., 1.4546}, {8., 1.57419},
    {9., 1.66504}, {10., 1.65835}, {11., 1.57831}, {12., 1.50497},
    {13., 1.49936}, {14., 1.55621}, {15., 1.61819}, {16., 1.6313},
    {17., 1.59014}, {18., 1.53661}, {19., 1.51863}, {20., 1.54824}}]
  \dataplot[plotstyle=curve,showpoints,dotstyle=triangle]{\mydata}
  \psline{<->}(0,2)(0,0)(22,0)
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.data}
[{0, 0}, {1., 0.946083}, {2., 1.60541}, {3., 1.84865}, {4., 1.7582},
 {5., 1.54993}, {6., 1.42469}, {7., 1.4546}, {8., 1.57419},
 {9., 1.66504}, {10., 1.65835}, {11., 1.57831}, {12., 1.50497},
 {13., 1.49936}, {14., 1.55621}, {15., 1.61819}, {16., 1.6313},
 {17., 1.59014}, {18., 1.53661}, {19., 1.51863}, {20., 1.54824}]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{pspicture}(4,3)
  \psset{xunit=.2cm,yunit=1.5cm}
  \readdata{\foo}{foo.data}
  \dataplot[plotstyle=curve,showpoints,dotstyle=diamond]{\foo}
  \psline{<->}(0,2)(0,0)(22,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile with `pdflatex --shell-escape filename.tex` or `xelatex --shell-escape filename.tex`.

```
%filename.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{xxx.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} 
\begin{document} 
\pspicture*[showgrid](-2,-1)(2,2) 
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1.75,-0.75)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=red]{-1.5}{1}{x^2+x} 
\endpspicture* 
\end{document} 
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\fig#1#2{
    \immediate\write18{xelatex #1}%
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{#1}
        \caption{#2}
        \label{fig:#1}
    \end{figure}%
}
\begin{document}
    \fig{xxx}{This is the graph of $y=f(x)=x^2+x$}
\end{document}
```

[image]