# TikZ: anchors of special node “current page” seem to be incorrect in landscape

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, landscape

I've got a document that I wish to format in landscape in conjunction with some material added as an overlay via TikZ.  I can get everything correct if I create a portrait page, but not if I create a landscape page.

Here's my MWE for *portrait* which shows what I want (except for page orientation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.south west) [text width=5cm,fill=red!20,above right] { This material is in the south west corner of the page };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I try to get the same effect in landscape, the `.south west` anchor is apparently off the page.  This seems to happen regardless of whether I pass `landscape` through the optional argument to the class declaration or through `geometry`.

Here's my malfunctioning MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.south west) [text width=5cm,fill=red!20,above right] { This material is in the south west corner of the page };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Following @HarishKumar's suggestion, I can see that my compilation route is part of the problem:  I'm compiling by: `latex` → `dvips` → `ps2pdf` instead of just `pdflatex`.  However, I was under the impression that I need to go the more round about way if I'm incorporating PostScript commands in my LaTeX document.  Does anyone know anything about this and care to explain why I should always use `pdflatex`?

Comment: You won't believe me. It works for both the cases (declaration in `documentclass` and through `geometry`) for me. But if you use `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` (`lscape` or `pdflscape` packages), then it won't work.

Comment: @HarishKumar.  :(   Maybe it's a difference of TeX versions?  I'm using TeX Live 2012 and doing `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` route.

Comment: Sorry forgot to write about it. I use miktex 2.9 updated just now, and always go by `pdflatex`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Could you make that an answer with an explanation of why my route is a bad choice?  I hadn't thought about the route I took.  `pdflatex` works fine.  I originally started going the route I use because I often do things with `pstricks` and was under the impression that I had to go that route.

Comment: @A.Ellett I used to think that too :) Have a look at [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413) There's a few things that don't work as they should when going the `latex=>dvips=>ps2pdf` route

Comment: @cmhughes.   I tried both the solutions suggested at the link you referenced.  For whatever the `xelatex` route fails (but I don't really know anything about `xelatex` and am not worried about that yet).  But the `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` route definitely works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a bit hesitant about calling this a bug in `pdflatex`, but from my not-very-extensive investigations, it would appear that the position returned by the primitive `\pdfsavepos` is offset when in landscape mode and producing dvi.  One way to explain the behaviour (though I've no idea how accurate this picture is) is that it is as if when `\pdfsavepos` runs then it actually computes the coordinates relative to the **bottom left** of the page.  But TeX wants the coordinates relative to the **top left** so then `pdflatex` has to compute `(0,paperheight) - (saved x, saved y)` and return that via `\pdfsavepos`.  However (still conjecturing) it's as if `pdflatex` when running in `dvi` mode does not know the actual page size of the shipped out page.  So when it computes `paperheight` then it uses its "standard" paper height.  This is based on the fact that the difference in the recorded positions in the aux file between a run with `latex` and a run with `pdflatex` is precisely `\paperheight-\paperwidth`:

`pdflatex` produces: `\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{10467319}{17617993}`

`latex` produces: `\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid1}{10467319}{29458709}`

The difference is 11840716 (the units are sp).

And (in landscape mode) we can compare that with the paper dimensions via:

```
\newdimen\stuff
\stuff=11840716sp
\showthe\stuff

\stuff=\paperwidth
\advance\stuff by -\paperheight
\showthe\stuff
```

then this produces:

```
> 180.67499pt.
l.9 \showthe\stuff

? 
> 180.67499pt.
l.13 \showthe\stuff
```

This explanation can't be completely right because although I get a similar story (in that there is a consistent y-shift) when I try `\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}` then the numbers don't add up in the same way.

For situations where one is going between two `tikzpicture` environments then this offset doesn't matter because it is consistent, and therefore the *relative* separation of the pictures is the same.  It only matters for the `current page` node as that is "absolutely" positioned.  To fix the `current page`, it suffices to fix where `pgf` thinks the page origin lies.  This is held in the macro `\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin` so we need to redefine that.

Ideally, we should redefine it to be aware of the current page size and geometry but as my experiments with `a5paper` showed me, I don't fully understand the computation involved.  So here's the fix for landscape a4paper when set using the `geometry` package.  If doing a mixed document, you could make the macro itself contain the conditional.  By surrounding it in `\ifpdf ... \fi` we get a system that works for both `latex` and `pdflatex`.

```
\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\else
\ifGm@landscape
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{11840716sp}}
\fi
\fi
\makeatother
```

In an adaptation of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91105/86}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\else
\ifGm@landscape
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{11840716sp}}
\fi
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\foreach \anchor in {north west,north east,south west,south east} {
    \node[anchor=\anchor] at (current page.\anchor) {some stuff at \anchor};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex` this produces:

[image: landscape absolute positioning with pdflatex]

With `latex; latex; dvips; pstopdf` (note the double run of `latex`) this produces:

[image: landscape absolute positioning with latex]

Answer (score 8):

pdflatex (and also lualatex) relies on the value of \pdfpageheight to calculate the position, but geometry doesn't set this value if the dvi-mode is used. If you adjust the lengths the nodes are placed correctly:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %for dvilualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}     % for current lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,landscape]{geometry}
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth %not sure if needed but can't harm
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4] 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.south west) [text width=5cm,fill=red!20,above right] { This material is in the south west corner of the page };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really fixed the problems I was having when using TikZ within headers in landscape mode when generating DVI.