# Trying to fix (or workaround) bugs that affect color-filled headers when going through DVI

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, fancyhdr, landscape, dvi

There's a problem that has been around since at least TeX Live 2015 to 2017 (but wasn't present in TeX Live 2012), and I'd like to find a fix or workaround for it, because it keeps me going to a machine with TeX Live 2012 when I need to generate some documents with solid-color filled headers in landscape mode.

To get a quick idea of the problem, here you have a picture with a comparison of the desired output (left column in the picture) and the incorrect output (right column) of the MWE given below. I get the correct output when I use `latex` and then `dvips`, and incorrect when using `dvilualatex` and then `dvips` (yes, the only difference is that the solid header doesn't arrive to the left in the incorrect output):

[image: output comparison]

The requirements I have for this kind of documents are as follows:

- The document must be in landscape and with big fonts (17pt when initialising the document class).
- Headers must have a solid color background and without white margins.
- Headers must be composed with the `fancyhdr` package.
- The output must be first DVI, then PS, and last of the pipeline, PDF.
- It must work with `dvilualatex`

I follow the solution given to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270414/complete-3-part-header-from-fancyhdr-inside-a-single-colored-box) *(it was posted by me years ago, but somehow my account got split in two when I tried to edit my nickname back then).*

Unfortunately, when using landscape mode, I hit a bug that affects TikZ and so I added the workaround given in [this question about the bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91105/tikz-anchors-of-special-node-current-page-seem-to-be-incorrect-in-landscape/).

Joining the solutions for these two questions, my code worked fine in TeX Live 2012. However, starting in TeX Live 2015 (perhaps sooner, as I jumped directly from 2012 to 2015), the code works with `latex` only, and not with `dvilualatex`.

So actually, it's two bugs rather than one (the bug in the TikZ behaviour when in landscape mode, and the bug making `dvilualatex` not filling the header up to the left limit).

My guess is that maybe I should focus in getting a good solution for the problem in TikZ, because first of all it makes my TeX file ugly (I really don't like its workaround, just look at the MWE below), and second, I feel it's quite possible that if I didn't have to use that workaround, I wouldn't hit the bug affecting `dvilualatex`.

In conclusion, if you have a solution for any of the following three questions, the problem would be solved:

- Do you know a better solution for the bug related to TikZ in landscape mode?
- Do you have an alternative approach (perhaps without TikZ, but remember that it must use `fancyhdr`) for getting the desired solid-color headers without hitting any of these bugs? (note that it must follow all the requirements from the bulleted list above)
- Does the `dvilualatex`-related bug (i.e.: the header not arriving to the left) have a solution?

Any (it doesn't matter which one) of these three questions solved would fix it.

The MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,17pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\usepackage[notindex,nottoc,notlot,notlof,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% Force new page at end of all types of sections
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\clearpage}
\newcommand\subsectionbreak{\clearpage}
\newcommand\subsubsectionbreak{\clearpage}
\newcommand\paragraphbreak{\clearpage}
\newcommand\subparagraphbreak{\clearpage}

% Define the header format
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\paragraphmark}[1]{\markright{\theparagraph\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraphmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubparagraph\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline]
   \fill[blue](current page.north west|-0,-\dp\strutbox)
   rectangle(current page.north east);
   \white{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline]
   \fill[blue](current page.north west|-0,-\dp\strutbox)
   rectangle(current page.north east);
   \white{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\white{\bfseries\thepage}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\white{\bfseries\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{14pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyfoot{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% Workaround for bug in TikZ when in landscape mode
\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\else
\ifGm@landscape
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{16240716sp}}
\fi
\fi
\makeatother
% (end of workaround)

% Rest of the document
\makeindex
\usepackage[dvips,colorlinks]{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\begin{document}
\date{\today}
\title{A M.W.E.}
\author{That's me}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\addtolength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
    \section{Quick comentary}
\index{Quick comentary}
Just a few words.\par
\section{Another section}
\index{Another section}
But as short as the other.\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for pointing it out, I had indeed two questions whose answers I didn't accept because I finally followed an alternate approach, but however they were right answers and it makes justice to accept them. Thank you for telling me.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, I do that when I have a solution. In these cases, however, the reason for not posting my solution is that I followed approaches that would be off-topic in a TeX discussion. Anyway, if you wish to continue this conversation, let me propose a private conversation, as I'd wish to get the comments here focused in the topic of the question (not a complaint, though, I really appreciate your comments).

Comment: I added an answer to your "tikz bug question". https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383708/2388. You don't need the work around. Add the luatex85 package and set \pdfpagewidth and \pdfpageheight.  This here is then a duplicate.

Comment: Btw: You can flag a moderator if you want to merge your two accounts again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the solution in the TikZ question. That question wasn't mine, so I cannot change the accepted solution, nor can I acknowledge (other than voting you up) that your solution is the answer I really needed. Anyway, you have just fixed one annoyance that accompanied me for a few years, so I'm really happy. Thanks a lot!!