# Changes in the \pdfsavepos offset across MacTeX versions when in landscape through dvi

Tags: tikz-pgf, landscape

Recently, I hit an scenario where the issue discussed in [TikZ: anchors of special node “current page” seem to be incorrect in landscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91105/tikz-anchors-of-special-node-current-page-seem-to-be-incorrect-in-landscape/) is critical for a document I'm generating, because of TikZ geometry-related instructions that get incorrect values when in landscape mode and generating dvi.

The answer by Loop Space in the above link is the only resource I found which discussed this problem.

However, in his proposed solution, which is the line `\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{11840716sp}}`, I had to change the numbers to `\pgfqpoint{0sp}{12940716sp}` (using MacTeX 2013) -found the right number by trial and error-. And now, I just updated to MacTeX 2015 and had to change it again, this time to `\pgfqpoint{0sp}{16240716sp}`. If I don't do these changes, it doesn't work for me in these MacTeX versions.

My concern is that this doesn't seem a good solution to this problem, if the needed number changes across different MacTeX versions, and so I don't know how should I address it.

I really need to generate DVI, and I need landscape mode too, so I don't know how to avoid this problem.