# How to make a frame for a single page in landscape programatically for letter and A4?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming, landscape

I recently completed running an international conference.  I hope to make certificates in a landscape orientation for the organizing committee, and some other attendees.  In order to make everything easier, I'm trying to use LaTeX to script as much as possible.  I've made a lot of headway outside the fact that there are different page sizes, paper, A4, etc.

I'm trying to make a background that looks likes this (ignore the non-framing, I lifted it from a JPG that was in a Word document used in past conferences):

[image: template]

Specifically, I the blue double-line on the outside.  I cannot seem to figure out how to make it programmatically so that I can use letter or A4 paper, and just math my way to success.

If anyone knows programmatically how to create this look, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: look at eso-pic package and its examples: https://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic

Comment: @Ignasi as I'm trying to make sure it works for different paper sizes, I don't know if that'll work.  I guess I could have two different templates that are selected based on paper size.

Comment: For a single page, tikz [overlay, remember picture] using (current page) anchors is easy.  I should be okay if the whole document is in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution, and it was an adventure.  It's worth noting that landscape makes everything difficult.  You really need to use the `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}` instead of the `pdflscape` packages because something runs off and messes up the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91105/
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\else
\ifGm@landscape
\def\pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfpageorigin{\pgfqpoint{0sp}{11840716sp}}
\fi
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\draw [line width=2pt,rounded corners=8pt]
   ($ (current page.north west) + (1.5cm,-1.5cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.5cm,1.5cm) $);

\draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=8pt]
   ($ (current page.north west) + (1.6cm,-1.6cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.south east) + (-1.6cm,1.6cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is close enough, and something to work with.

[image]

Comment: Tikz is known not to like changes in the page geometry (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering)

Comment: It may be better to pass `landscape` to the class so everything picks it up (everything which is interested).