# How do import pdf pages when using latex-dvips-ps2pdf?

Tags: pstricks, pdfpages, ps2pdf

I would like to insert some `pdf` pages from a different file into the one I am working on currently. I understand that I can use the `pdfpages` package.

However, I am using `pstricks` and therefore have to compile my file with

```
latex-dvips-ps2pdf
```

and not `pdflatex`. Is there a work around? I am a newbie, so a detailed explanation would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You can use `pdflatex` with `PSTricks` as detailed in [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413) . The manual also states the `pdfpages` supports `xelatex`