# I get a bad result when creating my first simple image with PSTricks

Tags: graphics, pstricks, pst-plot

I get a bad result when creating my first simple image with PSTricks.

I get:

> 0 Errors, 2 Warnings

but... bad results.

What am I doing wrong?

My files can be downloaded at
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56475675/intento_simple.zip

I understand many PSTricks lines, but... I'm doing something wrong in the `.tex` file

Must I compile with LaTeX? or ... Can I compile with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Please have a look at other questions and also visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) for a prediction of why your question will be considered as a bad one and won't be answered if you don't edit it by the link below your question.

Comment: You can use `pdflatex`, you just need to follow some steps: [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413)

Comment: OK, Thank you very much. Your help was very usefull. Excuse me.