# pstricks and caa.cls

Tags: pstricks, document-classes

I have a TeX file that my prof gave me and I can't get it to work.

First, I don't know what package allows me to use

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{caa}.
```

Next, I have a bunch of `pscurves`, `pslines`, and such that give me `!undefined control sequence errors`. I have tried to compile using everything `texmaker.exe` allows me to use; i.e. `pdflatex`, `PS->PDF`, and such. Nothing works.

I am using Windows, I have MiKTeX, I have tried MiKTeX package manager, typed keyword: `pstricks` and installed all packages that popped up for it. Not sure what to next.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got `pstricks` matter in your document, there are two approaches.  (1) If you leave that code in your document, then using `pdflatex` will result in the sort of error you're talking about. (2) You can put the `pstricks` material in separate files, compile those files separately (as you normally would), and then important the resulting `pdf`s as graphics using `\includegraphic`

Regardless, the way to compile a file containing `pstricks` material is by

```
latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf
```

Regarding `caa.cls`, I'm not sure what that class is.  It's perhaps something someone at your site wrote.

Comment: thanks i can now view it on yap under .div formate which is sufficient. I can't get the pstricks to load, but don't need them right now.  The caa.cls is suppose to be an alternative to amsart but for thesis, i guess.  I haven't seen much on the web about it.

Comment: @user60675, if you can duplicate the error in a MWE using the `amsart` class, then perhaps we can help you a bit better.

Comment: you can also use `xelatex` and even `pdflatex` if you follow http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex

Comment: @cmhughes Regarding `pdflatex`, very true.  I'd forgotten that.  But, I've not always been happy with the results.  I've only dabbled in `xelatex` and don't know it very well; perhaps you should write up an answer encompassing `xelatex`.

Comment: @cmhughes I think where I've run into difficulty with the `pdflatex` approach is when my `pstricks` code is so embedded  into the document that separating is not always possible.  For example, I write quizzes for which each version gets a slightly differently oriented version of the picture (though that could be worked around).  But I not too infrequently place multiple nodes throughout the document outside of a `pspicture` environment.