# Problems using pst-node/Undefined Control Sequence-- PStricks

Tags: pstricks

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pst-coil}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
        \rput(3,3){\circlenode{P1}{$P_t$}}
        \rput(1,1){\circlenode}{a1}{$a_1$}}
        \rput(5,1){\circlenode}{a2}{$a_2$}}
        \ncline{->}{P1}{a1}
        \ncline{->}{a1}{a2}
        \ncline{->}{a2}{P1}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried this code in Linux and windows, with LyX and Texmaker and I always obtain the same problem:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...\expandafter \c@lor@to@ps #1#2\@@
\else \expandafter \expand...
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.13 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,0)(4,4)
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <5> on input line 14.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.14 \rput(3,3){\circlenode{P1}{$P_t$}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.14 \rput(3,3){\circlenode{P1}{$P_t$}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.14 \rput(3,3){\circlenode{P1}{$P_t$}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.14 \rput(3,3){\circlenode{P1}{$P_t$}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Argument of \circlenode@i has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.15 \rput(1,1){\circlenode}
{a1}{$a_1$}}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \circlenode@i was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.15 \rput(1,1){\circlenode}
{a1}{$a_1$}}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.15 \rput(1,1){\circlenode}{a1}{$a_1$}}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Argument of \circlenode@i has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.16 \rput(5,1){\circlenode}
{a2}{$a_2$}}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \circlenode@i was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.16 \rput(5,1){\circlenode}
{a2}{$a_2$}}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.16 \rput(5,1){\circlenode}{a2}{$a_2$}}
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.17 \ncline{->}{P1}{a1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.17 \ncline{->}{P1}{a1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.17 \ncline{->}{P1}{a1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.17 \ncline{->}{P1}{a1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.18 \ncline{->}{a1}{a2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.18 \ncline{->}{a1}{a2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.18 \ncline{->}{a1}{a2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.18 \ncline{->}{a1}{a2}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.19 \ncline{->}{a2}{P1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.19 \ncline{->}{a2}{P1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps
l.19 \ncline{->}{a2}{P1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...string \color@ #1#2\endcsname \@@
\fi \space
l.19 \ncline{->}{a2}{P1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
[1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!] (G:\PRACTICAS-LATEX\PracticaFlujo.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
7307 strings out of 493921
124000 string characters out of 3147282
259467 words of memory out of 3000000
10560 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
37i,5n,57p,570b,202s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program F
iles/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiK
TeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
Output written on PracticaFlujo.pdf (1 page, 33495 bytes).
PDF statistics:
22 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thanks

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex help? If so, this is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I've seen the post and i've ran texmaker with xelatex and i have this error message:   ! Argument of \circlenode@i has an extra }. Thanks

Comment: You have a couple of extra `}` after the second and third `\circlenode`: if I remove them all is OK with XeLaTeX.