# pstricks compile problem

Tags: pstricks

I know this issue has been discussed a lot in other topics, but most of them contain complex examples, from which I haven't been able to understand the solution. So I have the following code:

```
 \documentclass{article} 
 \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} 
%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}

 \begin{document}    
 \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.8)(2.0,0.8) 
 \psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,0.78)(1.98,-0.78) \end{pspicture} 
 \end{document}
```

I keep getting the error message: Undefined control sequence. What am I doing wrong? (I'm using texmaker in ubuntu).

Comment: Are  you using `pdflatex` or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`?

Comment: I'm using pdflatex

Comment: Did you compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename.tex`?

Comment: @Marienplatz It seems that the obtained line is the line of OP's activity. ;-)

Comment: I compiled it through texmaker with pdflatex, don't know how to use -shell-escape in that.

Comment: @StavrosPoupakis From the text window you can write in the directory of your file `pdflatex -shell-escape YourFile`. The extension `tex` is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Viewing this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/15278) may help you.

To keep this answer short.

- You can either use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. In this case you should remove the `[pdf]` option from the `pstricks` package.
- Or you can use `pdflatex` with the modification proposed in a previous comment or the afforementioned [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/15278). To do that you should go to the tab shown in the image.

  [image: texmaker preferences tab]

  On this tab you should modify the command for pdfLatex from `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` to `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`.

  My understanding is that this will create some PDF files with the images. I don't know if they are automatically being merged to the rest of the document though.

If you don't really need `pdflatex` for a spefic reason, other than `pstricks`, then I would suggest changing to `xelatex`. In my opinion it provides a "cleaner" approach to the matter.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

insert the option `--shell-escape` into your configuration for `pdflatex/latex/xelatex`:

[image]