# Installing the sfg package

Tags: packages, installing, graphs

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit, with MiKTeX and TeXstudio. I want to draw signal flow graphs in LaTeX, so I have "installed" the sfg package, along with pstricks and fp (the prerequisites). Unfortunately, when I try to execute a minimal file, I get an undefined control sequence error message. Here's the minimal file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks,sfg}
\begin{document}

Testing.

\sfgsetunit{0.5cm}  
\sfgsetsize{0.12}{0.4}{0.5}{0.3}  
\sfgsetcompass 
\begin{picture}(27,4) % % branches related to node 2 
\put(6,2){\sfgbranch{3}{0}\S{$\frac{1}{R_1}$}} 
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

The command that LaTeX doesn't like is the first uncommented `sfgbranch` command in the picture environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any update? Does your problem still exist?

Comment: Sorry. Many thanks for your answer. I haven't had time to go through your suggestions yet. I'll definitely let you know when I've done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First make sure that you installed the package correctly - here's a
>   tutorial (I made it for another purpose):
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OD15rZO_rD8

### Important

> This is only a **partial answer**: I couldn't figure it out how to use
>   `pdflatex`.

### First Guess

You are probably using `pdflatex` in order to compile. This doesn't work out of the box. After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142290) question I tried `xelatex` for example and get the following output:

[image]

### Alternative

But maybe you want to use a more up to date solution - have a look at the some of the `tikz` (which is another package - it works with pdflatex without problems) examples here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/

Comment: I can get the signalflowdiagram stuff to work in the tikz example page. That looks like a very workable solution. The xelatex command I'm very unfamiliar with. It didn't seem to produce any output! Thanks much.