# Multiple files with new command causes undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, pstricks

I am working on a scientific paper and recently I moved from Ubuntu with TeX Live to Mac OS. My document is splitted on more `.tex` files, to make it easier to work over it. With my old latex machine I had no issues at all, my pdf were genereted as intended.

Right now, I am having an undefined control sequence on the tex sources where is used a command defined on the root file. First thing I checked was if I had all the needed packages are installed correctly, but it seems I am not missing anything. My source looks like this.

**main.tex**

```
[ ... ]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[1]{\pscirclebox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
[ ... ]
\begin{document}

\input{auxiliary}
```

**auxiliary.tex**

```
\chapter{Elements of something }
Whatever.
\section{Whatever}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=2cm,rowsep=3cm]
        & \mycircle{S_2}    &   \\
\mycircle{S_1}  &           & \mycircle{S_3} 
\psset{arrows=->,labelsep=3pt,nodesep=3pt}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{1,2}{2,1}\ncput*{$0.2$}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{2,1}{1,2}\ncput*{$0.3$}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{2,3}{2,1}\ncput*{$0.1$}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{2,1}{2,3}\ncput*{$0.1$}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{2,3}{1,2}\ncput*{$0.7$}
\ncarc[arcangle=-20]{1,2}{2,3}\ncput*{$0.3$}
\nccircle{->}{1,2}{.6cm}\ncput*{$0.5$}
\nccircle[angleA=120]{->}{2,1}{.6cm}\ncput*{$0.6$}
\nccircle[angleA=240]{->}{2,3}{.6cm}\ncput*{$0.2$}
\end{psmatrix}
\vspace{0.8cm}
\caption{Bla bla.}
\label{fig:weather}
\end{figure}
```

What I receive is an Undefined Control Sequence pointing to that `\mycircle` on `auxiliary.tex`. Someone has any idea on how I should resolve this?
What I can't understand is why the same document with no differences was working on the other latex distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pstricks`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pstricks) and its packages needs some care when compiling. You can either use `xelatex` or else the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` routine; you can use `pdflatex`, but you have to ask it correctly as detailed in [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex)

Presumably, your old setup had one of these compilation sequences to be used by default.

Here is your code mocked up into a complete MWE- note that I have used the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) tool to help with the automation- simply run

```
arara main
```

to get a pdf

## `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
% arara: latex
% arara: dvips
% arara: ps2pdf
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[1]{\pscirclebox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\input{auxiliary}

\end{document}
```

## `xelatex`

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[1]{\pscirclebox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\input{auxiliary}

\end{document}
```

## `pdflatex`

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\newcommand{\mycircle}[1]{\pscirclebox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\input{auxiliary}

\end{document}
```

I didn't change `auxilary.tex`.

If you'd prefer not to use `arara`, then you'll have to run the commands either using the command line, or by telling your editor/development environment the correct commands- `arara` makes all this *much* easier.

Comment: Thank you! Arara and your suggestions resolved the problem! :)