# Fill opacity problem with pdflatex while upgrading MiKTeX from version 2.7 to 2.9

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, transparency

It's my first post. I solved it when writing this so I send it anyway in case it helps someone.

When compiled with pdflatex.exe from MiKTeX 2.7 it works. When compiled with `pdflatex.exe` from MiKTeX 2.9 the `fill opacity` property of `\addplot` also compiles without errors but when opened in a pdf reader, the reader returns error: `pgf@ca0.5 blablabla`.

To fix this problem (I don't know why) you should avoid using packages: `pstricks`, `pst-node`, `pst-plot`, `pst-circ`.

Here's my corrected code

```
\documentclass[addressstd,a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}

\addplot [black,thick,ybar interval,fill=black,] 
    coordinates {(22.1,68.9) (44.2,74.4) (88.4,86.5)};
\addlegendentry{one};

\addplot [blue,thick,ybar interval,fill=blue,fill opacity=.5] 
    coordinates {(22.1,78.9) (44.2,64.4) (88.4,86.5)};
\addlegendentry{two};

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  I see no problem with your code, apart from suprious `;` after the legends, and the output is fine when I run in a `pstricks` compatible way.  Which engine are you using?  Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413/15925?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The problem (perhaps not in the code) is when uncomment the line:
%\usepackage{pstricks, pst-node, pst-plot, pst-circ}

using miktex 2.9 pdflatex (I am using texnic 1.0 to compile)

Comment: Ernesto, this issue is very, very probably not related to MiKTeX itself, but to the fact that in MiKTeX 2.7 you necessarily have older package versions of pgf/TikZ and PSTricks & co.

Comment: My remarks about the output applied to when the line was uncommented.

Comment: Speravir: Thanks for the hint on versions (Miktex, pgf/Tikz and PSTricks). I put the label Miktex because it was how I (and perhaps others) identified the problem. It was hard, for me, to discover that the problem was in packages versions not in the compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use it this way:

```
[...]
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\ifpdf\else
  \usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-plot,pst-circ}
  \psset{pgffunctions}
\fi
\begin{document}
[...]
```

then it will work with `pdflatex --shell-escape`, `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`, and `xelatex`

Comment: good answer! I can not vote because "my reputation" < 15

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't use pstricks, pst-node, etc. but still experienced the same problem, I found the following answer to provide a fundamental explanation for the observed problem:

[Tikz and ctable incompatibility, gives error when printing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253401/tikz-and-ctable-incompatibility-gives-error-when-printing)

In short, moving the following snippet in front of the remaining packages solved the problem of adobe reader reporting errors when viewing a pgfplot that made use of opacity:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@transparent.sty}{}
\makeatother
%remaining packages
```