# Tikz and ctable incompatibility, gives error when printing

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, printing, transparency, ctable

When I print a report I get an error:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
>   correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem

After a lot of debugging, I've found that this MWE reproduces the problem. I've tried it on three different computers with the same error.

```
\documentclass{standalone}          
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When loading the ctable package, the image is changed (the opacity disappears), so it seems the error comes from some incompatibility between ctable and opacity in tikz. **The error only appears when trying to print though, acrobat before attempting to print.** (Printing either to a pdf file or to a real printer)

I have the following versions of tikz and ctable:

> tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0
>   ctable.sty    2014/04/25 v1.29

How can I fix this?

---

EDIT: I found the warning `Transparency disabled: incompatible with tikz package` from ctable so I guess this incompatibility can explain the error in the first MWE.

However, I continued digging and found that the spy library seem to be incompatible with ctable as well.

Here's an MWE that generates the same error when printing (either to a pdf file or to a real printer):

```
\documentclass{standalone}          
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={size=2cm,connect spies}]
\begin{scope}
\spy on (-3,.25) in node at (2,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There seem to be a serious problem with using tikz + ctable, can it be fixed?

Comment: If you look at the documentation if it sees that tikz is loaded it gives up on the transparency hence it is not a bug but a choice. A strange choice I would say. Do you need to use `ctable`?

Comment: @percusse I see. The second example with the `spy`-library is then probably a totally unrelated issue. I don't need to but it would be nice to avoid changing all the tables in the report (I noticed this error quite late in the project, haven't printed the report for proofreading earlier).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Package `ctable` loads package `transparent`. Both package `transparent` and `tikz` implements transparency. This needs access to a page resource, a dictionary `ExtGState` for the transparent values. Unhappily, the LaTeX format has overslept the PDF development quite entirely. Managing global resources is the prime task for an OS, format in TeX speek. Because of the missing resource manager, both packages do what most packages do, they think they are alone and add their stuff to the resource, `\pdfpageresources` in this case. The result for

```
% PDF file without compression for easier reading/analyzing
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfcompresslevel=0

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PDF object 4 contains the `Resources` for the page (reformatted):

```pdf
4 0 obj
<<
  /ColorSpace 3 0 R
  /Pattern 2 0 R
  /ExtGState 1 0 R % by TikZ, see next object
  /ExtGState <<    % by package transparent
    /TRP1 << /ca 1 /CA 1 >>
  >>
  /ProcSet [ /PDF ]
>>
endobj

1 0 obj
<<
  /pgf@CA.5 << /CA .5 >>
  /pgf@ca.5 << /ca .5 >>
>>
endobj
```

As can be seen, the dictionary `Resources` (object 4) contains two entries `ExtGState`, which is not allowed by the PDF specification. Now it's up to the PDF reader, how it resolves the issue and which entry is used. Thus its by accident, if the PDF works for which program/printer. If the transparency of both packages are used in the page, then there will be always an error, because one of the `ExtGState` is missing at any case. Otherwise there is a 50:50 chance, that the PDF viewer/printer picks the unused `ExtGState` and throws away the other.

If you do not need the transparency of `ctable`/`transparent`, then you can fool LaTeX in thinking, that `transparent` is already loaded:

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@transparent.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{ctable}
```

Package `ctable` could provide an option for turning transparency off.

### Patch for `transparent` to use package `pgf`'s resource management

The following patch is applied after package `transparent` is loaded.
Then it cooperates with package `pgf` by using the macro `\pgfutil@addresource@extgs` for the transparent settings and the transparency methods of *both* packages can be used.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}

\makeatletter
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs\endcsname\relax
\else
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    % \pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain{%
    \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs{%
      \TRP@list
    }%
  }%  
  \let\TRP@addresource\relax
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello \texttransparent{.3}{World}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter 
\end{document}
```

Also the disabling of `\transparent` by package `ctable` can be undone. The warning remains, but can be ignored.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{transparent}
\let\OriginalTransparent=\transparent

\makeatletter
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs\endcsname\relax
\else
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    % \pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain{%
    \pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs{%
      \TRP@list
    }%
  }%
  \let\TRP@addresource\relax
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{ctable}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\transparent=\OriginalTransparent
}

\begin{document}
Hello \texttransparent{.3}{World}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\end{document}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Awesome. It would, imho, perhaps be a good idea to mention this "trick" in the `ctable` documentation, do you think it would be a good idea to suggest this to the maintainer?

Comment: @Grimler I plan to update `transparent` to cooperate with `pgf`/TikZ.

Comment: This example does not work any more. Add \usepackage{scrlfile} and change \usepackage{ctable} to \AfterPackage{tikz}{\usepackage{ctable}}

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger Make a bug report for `ctable`. The error message after `\usepackage{tikz,transparent,ctable}` with `You must load ctable after tikz` is wrong, since `ctable` is loaded after `tikz`. Also there is another logic error,  `ctable` looks for package `transparent`, but defines a dummy `\transparent` in some situation, which causes an already defined error message, when `transparent` is loaded later.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Bugreport sent by email to the maintainer...

Comment: heiko, Ulrike just raised this as an issue on github, should we fix it at source there? https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/19

Comment: As of almost the end of the year and the problem still persists.  Just stumbled upon this in a hard way... Produced files open gracefully on my side with SumatraPDF, but Adobe Acrobat Reader on the receiver side makes a problem out of this.