# Disable transparency warning when using ctable with pgfplots?

Tags: tables, pgfplots, footnotes, ctable

I'm using [ctable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) package for tables with footnotes. IMO it looks better than using [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) with [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package. I also use [pgfplots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (which I guess uses tikz package, in turn). Everything works perfectly. Problem is that ctable throws a warning:

```
Package ctable Warning:  Transparency disabled: incompatible with tikz package on input line 5.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
Content here.
\end{document}
```

I doesn't seem to affect anything and my PDF looks fine.

**Q: Is there any simple way to disable the warning?** I'm using Overleaf.

Or can I disable ctable transparency feature? Are there other possible alternatives or should I just live with the warning.

Comment: Have a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253401/tikz-and-ctable-incompatibility-gives-error-when-printing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You asked to surpess the warning. I am not sure if you really want to have this solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{ctable}{Transparency disabled:}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
Content here.
\end{document}
```

It only surpress the warning. A bugreport has been sent to the maintainer a few minutes ago...

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed. Not that this is the optimal solution but it will suffice until the transparency/incompatibility issue is properly resolved. And thanks for sending the bug report. I hope ctable is still maintained. Or some other package gets better support for table footnotes.

Comment: I got response from the maintainer and he will send a notification if the problem is resolved.