# Transparent package alters tikz color opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, color, transparency

When using the package [transparent](https://ctan.org/pkg/transparent) for some elements in text, it has a huge side effect: it alters the colors also in any Ti*k*Z image of the document.

This is the result without using the package:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

Some transparent text.

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is the result using the package:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Some \texttransparent{0.5}{transparent} text.

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=yellow,opacity=0.2] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The correct color for the square is the *fist* one; the correct transparency for the text is the *second* one. How to avoid this, having both features at the same time? (Not necessarily using [transparent](https://ctan.org/pkg/transparent)).

---

This error generates using TeXstudio 2.10.8 (hg 5802:5ee1d048e556), Qt Version 5.5.1, in Ubuntu 16.04 (all packages are up-to-date), with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/LxAk4vAX) is the logfile.

Comment: can't reproduce with pdflatex from texlive 2018

Comment: Which tex distribution do you have? Which engine do you use?

Comment: @book I can reproduce this result using `pdftex` with `MikTeX's` latest distribution.

Comment: @book TeXstudio 2.10.8 (hg 5802:5ee1d048e556), Qt Version 5.5.1, in Ubuntu 16.04, with `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

Comment: The tex distribution is the one from Ubuntu repository, currently up-to-date. I am not sure about how to give you its precise version.

Comment: Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added as a link at the end of the question.

Comment: Check the transparent version in the log-file. You need version 2018/11/18 v1.3 for this to work. We just added the necessary compability code. See https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/19 @Raaja this is for you too.

Comment: Your system is outdated, in texlive 2015 it won't workb (unless you add the needed patch yourself).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Having installed from Ubuntu repository (and not being very skilled about this), it is more difficult to update to this newer version. However, it works with the patch in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253417/74786). Thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just updated all my TeX packages, and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating the package.