# Clash of the ctable package with the datetime package if the showdow option is set

Tags: packages, datetime2, ctable

Loading the datetime2 package with the showdow option creates a clash with the ctable package, at least for me. Without the showdow option there are no problems. The following MWE shows the error message and the output as comments in lines 12 and 13.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex 
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[showdow,en-US]{datetime2}
%\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2} causes no problem

\begin{document}
Month: \DTMmonthname{2}.
%Error line 11: Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
%Output: /TRP1«/ca1/CA 1» Month: February.
\end{document}
```

Comment: load also pgf: \usepackage{pgf}

Comment: It works like a charm. Can you give a brief explanation, perhaps as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example can be reduced to this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent} %loaded by ctable
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} %loaded by datetime

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

transparent must add transparency settings to a global dictionary inside the pdf (to the `/ExtGState`) and has to coordinate this with the pgf package that wants to add settings to this resource too (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253417/2388 for a description why this is needed).

For this transparent checks if the pgf command `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` exists and uses it if yes. Sadly the `pgfcalendar` package loads only parts of the pgf files and so `\pgfutil@addpdfresource@extgs` exists but errors. A real solution would require that `pgfcalendar` loads at least `pgfcore` instead of only `pgfrcs`.

## Work-arounds

load `pgfcore` or some package that loads it implicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent} %loaded by ctable
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} % loaded by datetime
\usepackage{pgfcore} %

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

Or use the LaTeX PDF management:

```
\DocumentMetadata{} %load PDF management
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{transparent} %loaded by ctable
\usepackage{pgfcalendar} % loaded by datetime


\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```