# Convert PSTricks to TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I use pstricks for all my graphics. Now I am submitting a paper to a [conference](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/AuthorKit.zip) which, unfortunately, does not allow to use PostScript. I have to send them tex source, which *they* compile with pdflatex. So, pstricks might not work (I am almost sure they won't apply the solutions here: [How to use PSTricks in pdfLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex)).

The only solution I found was to convert PStricks to TikZ. Is there an automatic converter for this task?

Comment: How about including pre-compiled images as part of your submission?

Comment: You are thinking too advanced for academia standards. Just compile your figures as pdf, eps whatever and inlcude them as straightforward images. Zip them in a folder and it's good to go.

Comment: You can create PDF images using the standalone class, for example

Comment: If PDF images are allowed to be included together with your main TeX source file (aka input file), then you can generate a PDF for each PSTricks diagram using `standalone` document class (to get a tight image without white borders) compiled with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (for faster compilation).

Comment: @Ohmyghost Thanks! This idea was very helpful. Can you make it an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoted from my comment [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200694/convert-pstricks-to-tikz?noredirect=1#comment466958_200694):

> If PDF images are allowed to be included together with your main TeX
>   source file (aka input file), then you can generate a PDF for each
>   PSTricks diagram using standalone document class (to get a tight image
>   without white borders) compiled with latex-dvips-ps2pdf (for faster
>   compilation).

To be more explicit:

- Go to each diagram in your main input file.
- Cut  each a pair of `\begin{pspicture}` and `\end{pspicture}`.
- Paste in a new document called `fig1.tex` and saved in a sub directory `Images`, having the following structure:

  ```
  % fig1.tex
  \documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% remove the border key if you want a tight output without any border.
  \begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(35,20)
  ...
  \end{pspicture}
  \end{document}
  ```
- Compile `fig1.tex` with either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (which is much faster) or `xelatex` (which is much slower). Here, using `pdflatex -shell-escape` does not make sense for creating  tight standalone diagrams.
- Check the newly created file `fig1.pdf` in `Images` sub directory.
- In your main document, put

  ```
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \graphicspath{{Images/}}
  ```

  in the preamble and for each diagram you want to import, do the following.

  ```
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig1.pdf}
  \caption{any caption}
  \label{anylabel}
  \end{figure}
  ```
- Remove `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` from your main input file.
- Compile the main input file with `pdflatex` to get a PDF output.
- Done.

Comment: To be honest, I really do what I wrote above in my daily job (not as a ghost).

Comment: To avoid many compilations, one can put every environment in the same file and use the option `standalone` provides to compile each picture in a separated page (each with the correct adjusted size).

Comment: @Manuel: It is not recommended as we will waste much time to compile during the development phase.

Comment: I understood he has already the images done, so it would be just one compilation, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Manuel: I prefer to provide the best practice approach. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can tell `standalone` not to recompile the images each time, although I haven't used this approach myself.