# How to backfit PStricks to PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pstricks

I have a 700+-page manuscript with 70+ PStricks figures like, for example, this one:

[image: A PStricks graphic I don't want to reset in TikZ.]

Some of my figures (though not the above example) even use the PostScript interpreter to compute the shape of a curve. Since `dvipdf` works even on these, it is obviously *possible* to translate all my figures to PDF. However, unfortunately, PDFLaTeX won't do it.

One would like to use modern tools like PDFLaTeX, XeTeX, etc.—especially, one would like to use PDFLaTeX.

The answer I am not looking for: convert to TikZ. I like TikZ. The next manuscript I write, I mean to use TikZ, but I've already sunk the hours into PStricks for this manuscript.

[Here is one clunky solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200758/95624) to a related problem. Surely however there is a better way to do what I want to do, isn't there? (There is also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29679/95624) but I don't think that it has to do with me.)

How can I backfit my PStricks figures to PDFLaTeX, please?

Comment: does it not work with `auto-pst-pdf` package? (most pstricks works with pdftex via that route, but not all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I will look into it again. I thought that I tried that a few years ago. It didn't work very well for anything as I recall, but it especially choked on those of my figures that include actual, direct PostScript code. But maybe I was using an old version of `auto-pst-pdf`? Or maybe I was using it wrong. Thanks for the helpful prod!

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` works only for `pspicture` environments. If you have not such an environment, e.g. a `psmatrix`, then you have to put that PSTricks related code into an environment `\begin{postscript} ... \end{postscript}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: By the way, today is the [second time](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287323/95624) in the past two years you have kindly answered a question of mine on this site. You and I are unacquainted except through these occasional questions, but I appreciate your answers and comments very much nevertheless.

Comment: @Herbert: a `postscript` environment! I didn't know about that. I will try it.

Comment: don't forget to use the optionsl argument `-shell-escape` for `pdflatex`

Comment: I would advise to extract the pstricks figures as standalone figures, and include the resulting `.pdf` figures with `\includegraphics`. It will be easier to manage.

Comment: [The clunky solution above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200758/95624) is the best way to manage a huge project as yours.