# Chess Notation with skak: How to highlight squares?

Tags: highlighting, chess, skak

i'm using the skak-package for some chess notation in a presentation. My only issue: How can i highlight various squares on the chessboard? Basic:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newgame
\fenboard{8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0} % FEN-notation, only one Queen
\showboard
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For example, i want to show the possible movements for a Queen on the board. I've tried the  `\highlight{}` command (see below), but it throws errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newgame
\fenboard{8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0} % FEN-notation, only one Queen
\showboard
\highlight{d4,d6}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Shown Error: `!Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps l.49 \end{frame}`.
I use Texmaker with PdfLatex.

So, whats wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `skak` package seems to need `pstricks` which, by itself, is not compatible with `pdflatex`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex

Comment: Thanks! I tried xelatex: no errors, but also no highlighting. Then trying latex->dvips->ps2pdf showed everything - but: The highlighting is just a black border around the selected squares. Is there an option to color the square?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the highlighting skak uses pstricks and you must load skak with the ps-Option:

```
 \usepackage[ps]{skak}
```

But I would suggest to use chessboard instead which will work with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{skak} %or xskak
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newgame
\chessboard[setfen=8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0,
            pgfstyle=border,markfields={d4,d6},
            color=blue!50,
            colorbackfield=c5,
            pgfstyle=color,
            opacity=0.5,
            color=red,
            markfield={d5}] 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are right, `chessboard` is a better choice for my needs. Thanks for the Example!

Comment: Why is there a blank square in the bottom right and how would I get rid of it?

Comment: @SomeT that indicated that white is to move. Check the documentation of chessboard if you want to disable it.