# How can I condense this code?

Tags: chess

It is a lot of lines, how can I condense this code so it is shorter? I just wanted to show how the queen moves on a chess board.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{skak} %or xskak
\usepackage{chessboard}



% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215330/chess-notation-with-skak-how-to-highlight-squares

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\newgame
\chessboard[setfen=8/8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0,
            % pgfstyle=border,markfields={d4,d6},
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=c5,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=b6,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=a7,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=e3,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=f2,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=g1,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d1,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d2,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d3,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d5,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d6,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d7,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=d8,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=c3,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=c4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=e4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=e5,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=a1,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=b2,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=f6,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=g7,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=h8,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=a4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=b4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=f4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=g4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            color=green!50,
            colorbackfield=h4,
            pgfstyle=color,
            % opacity=0.5,
            % color=red,
            %markfield={d5}
            ] 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With "condense" do you mean we should golf that code far beyond being illegible?

Comment: You don't need to set `color=green!50,pgfstyle=color,` over and over again. Just once is enough

Comment: Skillmon not sure what you are referring to in the game of golf but this relates more to chess? @Phelype Oleinik I thought that and it works, however do I really have to write colour back field each time?

Comment: Code golfing means to reduce code as much as possible while still doing the same thing. For reference: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah ok, then I guess I want to do that.

Comment: ```colorbackfields={b5,c6}``` I found this here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf but does not work

Comment: You really don't want a golfed answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192737/77083

Comment: @Skillmon of course there's [Tips for golfing in TeX/LaTeX](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123901/tips-for-golfing-in-tex-latex) if the OP really wants to go down that route. @ SomeT on behalf of your future self, don't golf code except for golfing contests.  Even normal code can be hard enough to read; golfed code can end up very similar to obfuscated code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With key-value arguments, you *usually* don't get anything by setting a key more than once.  There may be exceptions, with keys that denote *actions* rather than settings.  `chessboard`'s keys are sometimes actions, so some of them have to be repeated, but in this case setting the colour, you don't need that, so you can remove all but one occurrence of `pgfstyle=color,color=green!50`, as they are redundant.

Then, searching for `colorbackfield` in the `chessboard` documentation brings up `colorbackfields`:

> [image]

so you're  down to:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\chessboard[
  setfen=8/8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0,
  color=green!50,
  colorbackfields={c5,b6,a7,e3,f2,g1,d1,d2,d3,d5,d6,d7,d8,c3,
                   c4,e4,e5,a1,b2,f6,g7,h8,a4,b4,f4,g4,h4},
  pgfstyle=color
]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer.....and also for the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

Phelype pointed out the package has a multivalued key here but if it had not (or like me you didn't look for package documentation) then you can compress the code just using general tex coding eg

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{skak,chessboard}
\def\z#1#2{\ifx.#1\else colorbackfield=#1#2,\expandafter\z\fi}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\expanded{\noexpand\chessboard[
setfen=8/8/8/8/3Q4/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 0,
pgfstyle=color,color=green!50,
\z c5b6a7e3f2g1d1d2d3d5d6d7d8c3c4e4e5a1b2f6g7h8a4b4f4g4h4..
]} 
\end{document}
```

I also removed `frame` as `\frame` is a one argument macro, a variant of `\fbox` which doesn't seem wanted here (and doesn't work as an environment)