# Run msc package with pdflatex instead of xelatex

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, auto-pst-pdf

I am using [msc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/msc/manual.pdf) Latex package for building sequence diagrams, but I can only run it with Xelatex, which I don't like, but apparently [it's possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex) I can use pdflatex if I run it with:

`pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` option.

But I am using Vim-Latex, and where do I specify this option? I cannot figure this out.

This is my vimrc:

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
function CompileXeTex()
    let oldCompileRule=g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'xelatex -aux-directory=F:/Vim/my_latex_doc/temp --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
    call Tex_RunLaTeX()
    let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf=oldCompileRule
endfunction
```

P.s. [This](http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/) says that with newest msc version all PSTricks dependancies are removed but I downloaded that version, put it instead of old one, but I still get such errors when running with pdflatex:

```
error| Undefined control sequence. \c@lor@to@ps
```

So I guess it still depends on PSTricks. Or unless it's not enough to change msc.sty? I just changed the contents of the file to new version.

**So my goal is to run this with Pdflatex instead of Xelatex**.

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\title{aaa}
\author{aaaaa}

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{In}

\section{aa}
\subsection{}

\begin{center}
\begin{msc}{Deactivate cc}
\setlength{\instdist}{9cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{2\envinstdist}
\declinst{cc}{}{C}
\declinst{tt}{}{T}
\nextlevel
\mess{NonceC}{cc}{tt}
\nextlevel[2]
\mess{\{$pu_C$, $[byebye]_{pr_C}\}_{pu_T}$}{cc}{tt}
\end{msc}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT: I added:**

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape $*'
```

to my vimrc as suggested, but I still get PSTricks error:

```
error| Option clash for package pstricks.
```

Comment: You should try to load `auto-pst-pdf ` and compile with the `-shell-escape` switch if your system is TeX Live, or `--enable-write18` if it's MiKTeX. This will allow compiling with d

Comment: I know that, but that's my question - how do I do it? I use vim, and where do I put that `-shell-escape` in my vimrc?

Comment: please always provide an example document that demonstrates the error. the error you show is unrelated to pstricks it is from the color package, usually if you give it a `[dvips]` option when you are using pdflatex rather than latex+dvips

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know vim. Having checked on the web, maybe this compilation rule: `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape $*'`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, but it says `Pattern not found: Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --shell-escape $*'`. @David I added code.

Comment: Well, you should find the actual rule for pdflatex, and add what is added when compiling from the command line — `-shell-escape`.

Comment: @Bernard Actually your command worked, just it's single dash before 'shell'! Anyways, it does not fix the problem, I now get error: error| Option clash for package pstricks.

Comment: @user1880405: I tested you code with latex, pdflatex and xelatex. It works fine with `latex` and`xelatex` ; it compiles without a problem with pdflatex, bute there is no image for the msc environment. So perhaps you'd better stck to `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: @Bernard Well Herbert posted good working solution. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way: packages which uses `PSTricks` should not be loaded when running `pdflatex` and, of course, `tikz` and `todonotes` should not be loaded when running `latex`. My example use the `postscript` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{todonotes}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\else
  \usepackage{msc}
\fi
\title{aaa}
\author{aaaaa}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{In}

\section{aa}
\subsection{b}

\begin{center}
\begin{postscript}
\begin{msc}{Deactivate cc}
\setlength{\instdist}{5cm}
\setlength{\envinstdist}{2\envinstdist}
\declinst{cc}{}{C}
\declinst{tt}{}{T}
\nextlevel
\mess{NonceC}{cc}{tt}
\nextlevel[2]
\mess{\{$pu_C$, $[byebye]_{pr_C}\}_{pu_T}$}{cc}{tt}
\end{msc}
\end{postscript}
\end{center}

\subsection{e}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm]
  \node[initial,state,accepting] (deact)      {$D$};
  \node[state]         (init) [right of=deact]  {$d$};


  \path[->] (deact) edge              node {issue} (init)
        (init) edge [bend left]  node {block} (deact);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is just great, works perfectly! I am just wondering, what's that `postscript environment`, cause I couln't find anything in google about it, would be nice to understand how it works.

Comment: run `texdoc pst-pdf` for more explanations

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use the development version of `msc.sty` found [here](http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/development/msc.sty), (linked from the very bottom of the official website, [here](http://satoss.uni.lu/software/mscpackage/)), bung that file in the directory you're compiling from, and it will compile straight to PDF no problem.