# Filling pattern between two path without axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween, pattern

I want to fill between two paths I created with a pattern. When I do so, the filling is always black. I would like other colors/patterns.

My MWE is :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, red, name path=A]
(-8,1.5) cos (-6,0) sin (-4,-1.5) cos (-2,0) sin (0,1.5) cos (2,0) sin (4,-1.5) cos (6,0) sin (8,1.5);
\draw[line width=2pt, black, dashed] (-8,0) -- (8,0);
\draw[line width=0.5pt, black, dashed, name path=B] (-8,-2) -- (8,-2);
\draw[->] (-8.2,-2) -- (8.2,-2) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (-8,-2.2) -- (-8,10.2) node[above] {$y$};
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{pattern=crosshatch};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove `pstricks` package, with  `XeLaTeX` there is no problem, if you want to use  pdflatex and to maintain `pstricks` this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/54817) give methods to do that

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\center
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick,red, name path=A]
(-8,1.5) cos (-6,0) sin (-4,-1.5) cos (-2,0) sin (0,1.5) cos (2,0) sin (4,-1.5) cos (6,0) sin (8,1.5);
\draw[line width=2pt, black, dashed] (-8,0) -- (8,0);
\draw[line width=0.5pt, black, dashed, name path=B] (-8,-2) -- (8,-2);
\draw[->] (-8.2,-2) -- (8.2,-2) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (-8,-2.2) -- (-8,10.2) node[above] {$y$};
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{pattern=crosshatch};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Another method without using `fillbetween` library just with a clipped grid inside your path, in this case you can control density of "pattern" with `scale` option

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
\let\clipbox\relax
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\path[clip]
(-8,1.5) cos (-6,0) sin (-4,-1.5) cos (-2,0) sin (0,1.5) cos (2,0) sin (4,-1.5) cos (6,0) 
sin (8,1.5)|-(-8,-2)--cycle;
\draw[rotate=30,step=0.3](-8,-6)grid(8,6);
\end{scope}

\draw[ultra thick,red]
(-8,1.5) cos (-6,0) sin (-4,-1.5) cos (-2,0) sin (0,1.5) cos (2,0) 
sin (4,-1.5) cos (6,0) sin (8,1.5);
\draw[line width=2pt, black, dashed] (-8,0) -- (8,0);
\draw[->] (-8.2,-2) -- (8.2,-2) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (-8,-2.2) -- (-8,10.2) node[above] {$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked but is it possible to change the width and rate of the patern ?

Comment: Answer updated.