# Include graphic with white background as transparent

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to create a graphic with pstricks and want to include a logo which has some white colored background. But I want this white background to be transparent.

I have tried to change the white background to transparency with `gimp` and save it as `ps` file but I think `ps` cannot deal with transparency. Unfortunately I cannot use `png` or `pdf` as far as I know, because I have to use `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf` when using pstricks.

Hopefully somebody can help me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(1,1)
\psframe[fillcolor=red, fillstyle=solid, linecolor=red](0,0)(1,1)
\rput[lb](0,0){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo.ps}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Since my background is not a simple red filled rectangle, it does not help me to color the white background of the logo in gimp (which would be the most simplest solution).

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a wrong assumption corrected in the comments.

Comment: @TeXnician: Why are you so fast in voting to close? While xelatex and auto-pst-pdf are possible work-arounds I wouldn't call them the perfect and only solutions -- e.g. dropping pstricks and creating the picture with tikz is another.

Comment: With `xelatex` this works for me however with `pdflatex` I have some problems. But you are right, I did assume that using `pstricks` I cannot include a `pdf` image and this solves my problem.

Comment: @Vanessa: `xelatex` has problems with transparency. However you can use `pdflatex` together with the package `auto-pst-pdf`