# Emergency stop with automatically generated pspicture

Tags: pstricks, chemistry, ps, pspicture

I have to show up with several `cdx` files in my document.
I didn't find a ChemDraw handling package for LaTeX, so I took the `cdx` files converted to `pdf` and imported them in inkscape, which I then could save as `tex` files containing the `cdx` content as `pspicture`.

Now I wanted to include the `tex` files into my LaTeX document, which couldn't deal with that. I got an Undefined control sequence in my document.aux (troubling line is bold):

```
\relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\catcode `"\active 
\bibstyle{biblatex}
\bibdata{x-2-2-blx,quellen}
\citation{biblatex-control}
\abx@aux@refcontext{none/global//global/global}
```

**\abx@aux@refcontext{none/global//global/global}**

```
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
```

I tried to reduce the problem to an MWE recognizing it wasn't minimal and now, I cannot reproduce it :-/

With the folliwing MWE, I got an *Undefined control sequence* for the third last line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
%\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} - either one of two
%\usepackage{pstricks-add} - commented out
\begin{document}
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: inkscape 0.92.3
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(718,922)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{1 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(41.9793042,780.79536604)
\lineto(37.03209961,788.66890119)
\lineto(37.06490601,788.0324571)
\lineto(37.0977124,786.93672346)
\closepath
}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you import the  .pdf graphic files?

Comment: `\abx@aux@refcontext` is a `biblatex` auxiliary command. It will only be recognised if you have `biblatex` loaded. The only way this command can end up in the aux file of a document that does not load `biblatex` is if the document used to have `\usepackage{biblatex}` and that line was removed on the last run. In your MWE you don't load `biblatex`, so you can't reproduce the problem there. Did you try to delete the temporary files (`.aux`, ...) and compile again?

Comment: @Bernard I ought to put in the `*.cdx` files, but I didn't find any package to include a `*.cdx`; although `BKChem` can save files as `cdx` it couldn't read/open the ChemDraw files at all -.- (which makes me wonder wether that's "real" `cdx`) I don't want to write this work with `LibreOffice` or - way more frustrating - with `MS Office`. Therefore, I'd like to include the formula / reactions as `postscript` and I got "automacitally made" `tex` files containing _one_ pspicture each. @moewe I _did_ delete every `LaTeX` file except `*.tex` "and`*.pdf`". Also my main problem here is `pspicture`...

Comment: Maybe you should update your question with the `.aux` file of your MWE then. The unknown `\abx@aux@refcontext` is *definitely* a `biblatex` command, and if it is in the `.aux` when `biblatex` is not loaded it stems from a previous run. This should be irrelevant to your question and you should remove it to avoid confusing people like me. For what it is worth I tried your MWE and it compiled fine with XeLaTeX (I only got a blank page, though). You can't compile PS stuff with pdfLaTeX out of the box. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PSTricks, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413/35864

Comment: delete all auxiliary files and everything will be fine.

Comment: @Herbert Unfortunately, this didn't help at all...

The error remains the same.

Comment: sure! At first you have to load `pstricks-add` and second do not run it with `pdflatex` when not loading package `auto-pst-pdf`

Comment: @Herbert Would it be a complicated task at the beginning to run it with a cli instead of a GUI...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run this document with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` in a command line interface and it should work. But you will see nothing in the created PDF, the used coordinates in your example do not really make sense.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
    %LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
    %%Creator: inkscape 0.92.3
    %%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
    \psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
    \begin{pspicture}(718,922)
    {
        \newrgbcolor{curcolor}{1 0 0}
        \pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
        {
            \newpath
            \moveto(41.9793042,780.79536604)
            \lineto(37.03209961,788.66890119)
            \lineto(37.06490601,788.0324571)
            \lineto(37.0977124,786.93672346)
            \closepath
        }
    }
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

this is the same (exports from inkscape are rubbish ...):

```
\psset{unit=.5pt}
\psframebox{%
\begin{pspicture}(718,922)
  \pspolygon*[linecolor=red](41.9,780.7)(37.0,788.6)(37.0,788.0)(37.0,786.9)
\end{pspicture}}
```