# Compile pdf/svg/eps image exported from LibreOffice Draw with latex

Tags: pdf, eps, svg, ghostscript, libre-office

I want to include a `.pdf`, `.svg` or `.eps` image which I exported from LibreOffice Draw with `\includegraphics` and compile it with `latex` (cannot use `pdflatex`).

The latex compile error message I get is

```
Error: /rangecheck in --setmiterlimit--
Operand stack:
   --nostringval--   0
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   1   3   %oparray_pop   2044   1   3   %oparray_pop   2025   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:960/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:2/20(G)--   --dict:150/200(L)--   --dict:205/300(L)--   --dict:46/200(L)--   --dict:150/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 1365495
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

How can one produce a `.pdf`, `.eps` or `.svg` from `.odg` that `latex` accepts?

Edit: So my workaround is now that I convert the `.pdf` exported from LibreOffice to `.ps` which can be compiled smoothly with `latex`.

Comment: You can select export from LO menu.

Comment: This is what I did - but it apparently produces a corrupted file.

Comment: What exactly is the reason that you cannot use 'pdflatex'? Do you encounter any problems when you try to switch? Maybe those problems are easier to solve than your current issue with the file formats. In any case, you can also try to convert the files externally (there are several terminal-based tools/solutions for different use cases) to a format that `latex` accepts. If you find something that works then you can also make a custom `\includegraphics` rule to automate the conversion.

Comment: I need to use the template of my institute which uses the package PSTricks and thus can be only compiled with `latex` - neither `.pdf`, `.eps` nor `.svg` exported from LibreOffice ever posed a problem whenever I created documents without this package and compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AKG maybe of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/29873

Comment: @DG' that page lead to the solution - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with `xelatex` instead of `latex`.