# How to run image and labelpath together?

Tags: asymptote

```
// https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/CDlabel.asy
//settings.tex="pdflatex";
size(10cm);
usepackage("graphicx");
import labelpath;
fill(unitcircle^^(scale(0.15)*unitcircle),evenodd+rgb(0.5,1,0.83));
label(minipage(
"\centering\scriptsize 
\textbf{
  \LARGE {\tt Your Title}\\
  \smallskip
  \small The authors}\\
\smallskip
\today\\
",6cm),(0,0.5));
label("Your Texts",(-0.6,0));
label("Your Texts",(0.6,0));
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#/media/File:LaTeX_project_logo_bird.svg
// label(graphic("logo.svg","height=2cm"),(0,-0.5));
labelpath("\textbf{ \large MACROPODS - Their Care, Breeding and the Rearing of Their Young\, by: David McCauley}",
          reverse(arc((0,0),0.88,-80,260)));
```

[image]

```
// https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/CDlabel.asy
settings.tex="pdflatex";
size(10cm);
usepackage("graphicx");
import labelpath;
fill(unitcircle^^(scale(0.15)*unitcircle),evenodd+rgb(0.5,1,0.83));
label(minipage(
"\centering\scriptsize 
\textbf{
  \LARGE {\tt Your Title}\\
  \smallskip
  \small The authors}\\
\smallskip
\today\\
",6cm),(0,0.5));
label("Your Texts",(-0.6,0));
label("Your Texts",(0.6,0));
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#/media/File:LaTeX_project_logo_bird.svg
label(graphic("logo.svg","height=2cm"),(0,-0.5));
```

[image]

Question:

How can I connect image and labelpath ?

Comment: I suggest to ask about gradient for labelpath in a separate question.

Comment: @g.kov You can help !? :-)

Comment: Well, there are plenty of people here who could possibly help. 
But first I'd like to clarify the question. 
"connect image and labelpath" sounds not clear enough.
Do you mean that you want to put an image somewhere along the path,
mixing it with the text? Do you expect that the image will appear
in its natural rectangle form, or distorted according to the curvature of the path?

Comment: @g.kov I wish both commands (`label(graphic("logo.svg","height=2cm"),(0,-0.5));` and `labelpath("\textbf{ \large MACROPODS - Their Care, Breeding and the Rearing of Their Young\, by: David McCauley}", reverse(arc((0,0),0.88,-80,260)));`) can run **together**. Actually, I have a problem with `settings.tex="pdflatex";` and `settings.tex="latex";`.

Comment: Labelpath uses pstricks, so you will need extra effort to use it with pdflatex. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8415/484.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Sorry, but I am not familiar with PSTricks and I still need an complete answer which I can imitate.

Comment: Try using `settings.tex = "xelatex";`. I don't know if this will work, but it might. Otherwise, convert your logo from `svg` to `eps` and use `settings.tex = "latex";`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Maybe, I will have to convert my logo as your suggestion. :-(

Comment: @CharlesStaats And `settings.tex = "xelatex";` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Since `labelpath` needs `settings.tex="latex";`, a workaround is to generate both outputs separately in `asy` environments and then overlay them. Therefore, you have to run  `pdfLaTeX`, then `Asymptote` twice and then `pdfLaTeX` again.
In this manner, the CD label´s output is `filename-2.eps` and `filename-2.eps-converted-to.pdf`, one of which can be include as `label(graphic("filename-2.eps"),(0,0));` in the first `asy` environment.

The command `clip` clips the current content to the CD label region and thus center the two graphic. `path c=circle((0,0),1); draw(c,white);` is a phantom white circle to obtain a square image (of almost 100x100).

Note: `filename` refers to the name of the `.tex` file, such as `filename.tex`

Output (`filename.pdf`):
[image]

MWE  tested with `TeXstudio` 3.0.0 and `TeX Live` 2020 (`filename.tex`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{asymptote}
        \begin{document}
            \begin{asy}
            //https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#/media/File:LaTeX_project_logo_bird.svg
            settings.tex="pdflatex";
            size(10cm);
            fill(unitcircle^^(scale(0.15)*unitcircle),evenodd+rgb(0.5,1,0.83));
            label(minipage(
            "\centering\scriptsize 
            \textbf{
            \LARGE {\tt Your Title}\\
            \smallskip
            \small The authors}\\
            \smallskip
            \today\\
            ",6cm),(0,0.5));
            label("Your Texts",(-0.6,0));
            label("Your Texts",(0.6,0));
            label(graphic("logo.pdf","height=2cm"),(0,-0.5));
            label(graphic("filename-2.eps"),(0,0));
            clip(unitcircle^^(scale(0.15)*unitcircle),evenodd);
            \end{asy}
            \begin{asy}
            // https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/CDlabel.asy
            settings.tex="latex";
            size(10cm);
            import labelpath;
            labelpath("\textbf{ \large MACROPODS - Their Care, Breeding and the Rearing of Their Young\, by: David McCauley}",
            reverse(arc((0,0),0.88,-80,260)));
            label(graphic("logo.pdf","height=2cm"),(0,-0.5));
            path c=circle((0,0),1);
            draw(c,white);
            \end{asy}    
\end{document}
```