# How to reuse a specificall PSTricks figure with pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, preamble

I have to use a preamble (see below) which is outdated (and, in my opinion, clogged with garbage).

My task is to set up the given preamble for using with `pdfLaTex`, and **if possible to clean it from outdated stuff (packages and settings) and garbabe or even replace with current stuff and if applicable to change the package order in order to avoid package conflicts**. The present `PSTricks` figure (see below) is an example in order to prove the success of the taken changes. I use `TeXnicCenter` with an up-to-date `MiKTeX` and `ActivePerl`. The whole document

```
\documentclass[
               a4paper,
               10pt,
               fleqn,
               twoside,
               onecolumn,
               openright
              ]{memoir}

\usepackage[
            usenames,
            dvipsnames
           ]{color} 
\usepackage[
            russian,
            english,
            ngerman
           ]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american voltages]{circuitikz}
%\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks} % added, leads to many ''Undefined control sequence.''-errors
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % alternatively added, leads to ''Command \psfragfig already defined.''-error
\usepackage{
            dsfont,
            psfrag,
            pstricks,
            pst-plot,
            pstricks-add,
            calc,
            subfig,
            pstool,
            subfig,
            subfloat,
            psfrag
           }
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            xcolor,
            graphicx,
            epsfig,
            epsf,
            ifthen,
            calc,
            icomma,
            array,
            url,
            bbding,
            amsmath,
            amsthm,
            amssymb,
            mathtools,
            calrsfs,
            siunitx,
            booktabs,
            appendix,
            boxedminipage,
            comment
           }
\usepackage[text]{esdiff}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\newlength{\tempdim}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{example}{Beispiel}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Übung}[chapter]
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\ifpdf
\usepackage[
            bookmarks = false,
            colorlinks
           ]{hyperref}
\else
\usepackage[
            dvips,
            bookmarks = false,
            colorlinks
            ]{hyperref}
\fi
\title{Aufgaben- und Lösungskatalog zu Grundlagen der Mess- und Regelungstechnik}
\includecomment{Frage}
\includecomment{KurzAntwort}
\includecomment{LangAntwort}

\begin{document}

  \frontmatter
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \clearpage
  \mainmatter

  \begin{figure}\centering\hfill
    \subfloat[Spannungsverlauf]{
      \setlength{\tempdim}{.4\linewidth/10}\psset{unit=\tempdim}
      \begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.5)(6,4)
        \psline{->}(0,4)
        \psline{->}(-1,0)(6,0)
        \psline[linestyle=dashed,linewidth=.2pt](0,3)(6,3)
        \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=.4pt,plotpoints=50,plotstyle=curve]{0}{5.9}{3 1 2.71828 x neg exp sub mul}
        \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=0.4pt](-1,.05)(0,.05)
        \uput[l](0,4){\tiny $v_\mathrm{c}(t)$}
        \uput[l](0,3){\tiny $1$}
        \uput[d](6,0.2){\tiny \strut$t$}
        \uput[d](0,0.2){\tiny \strut$0$}
      \end{pspicture}\label{fig_capacitor_charge}}\hfill
    \subfloat[Audiosignal]{
      \setlength{\tempdim}{.4\linewidth/10}\psset{unit=\tempdim}
      \begin{pspicture}(-1,-2.5)(6.5,2.5)
        \psline{->}(0,-2)(0,2.5)
        \psline{->}(0,-2)(6.5,-2)\uput[d](6.5,-1.8){\tiny \strut$t$}
        \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=.4pt](0.00,0.09)(0.01,0.21)(0.02,-0.66)(0.03,0.02)(0.04,-0.69)(0.05,0.25)(0.06,-0.00)(0.07,-0.47)(0.08,0.01)(0.09,-0.52)(0.10,0.02)(0.11,-1.20)(0.12,-0.30)(0.13,0.12)(0.14,-0.47)(0.15,-0.72)(0.16,-0.32)(0.17,0.42)(0.18,0.42)(0.19,-0.09)(0.20,-0.40)(0.21,-0.02)(0.22,-0.92)(0.23,0.38)(0.24,-1.01)(0.25,-0.01)(0.26,-0.18)(0.27,-0.04)(0.28,0.49)(0.29,-0.18)(0.30,-0.11)(0.31,-0.12)(0.32,1.53)(0.33,-0.12)(0.34,1.03)(0.35,-0.02)(0.36,0.64)(0.37,0.36)(0.38,0.35)(0.39,0.98)(0.40,-0.35)(0.41,-0.18)(0.42,-0.15)(0.43,1.41)(0.44,-0.01)(0.45,0.63)(0.46,0.37)(0.47,-0.23)(0.48,0.25)(0.49,-0.06)(0.50,0.33)(0.51,0.14)(0.52,-0.14)(0.53,0.91)(0.54,-0.73)(0.55,0.15)(0.56,1.44)(0.57,0.03)(0.58,-0.31)(0.59,-0.12)(0.60,-0.54)(0.61,0.39)(0.62,-0.14)(0.63,0.02)(0.64,-0.44)(0.65,-1.84)(0.66,0.18)(0.67,0.22)(0.68,-0.16)(0.69,0.53)(0.70,0.41)(0.71,-0.22)(0.72,0.20)(0.73,0.23)(0.74,0.22)(0.75,0.25)(0.76,-1.21)(0.77,0.78)(0.78,2.52)(0.79,0.33)(0.80,-0.36)(0.81,-0.36)(0.82,-0.40)(0.83,0.10)(0.84,-0.03)(0.85,0.02)(0.86,0.32)(0.87,0.63)(0.88,1.06)(0.89,-0.06)(0.90,-0.07)(0.91,-1.24)(0.92,-0.41)(0.93,0.13)(0.94,0.66)(0.95,-0.06)(0.96,0.49)(0.97,-0.35)(0.98,-0.06)(0.99,-0.78)(1.00,0.22)(1.01,1.14)(1.02,-0.94)(1.03,0.74)(1.04,-1.35)(1.05,0.07)(1.06,1.82)(1.07,0.70)(1.08,-0.01)(1.09,0.38)(1.10,0.10)(1.11,0.46)(1.12,-1.23)(1.13,-1.49)(1.14,-0.18)(1.15,-0.19)(1.16,0.40)(1.17,-0.05)(1.18,-0.80)(1.19,0.24)(1.20,0.30)(1.21,-0.03)(1.22,-1.42)(1.23,0.43)(1.24,-0.90)(1.25,0.41)(1.26,0.26)(1.27,0.07)(1.28,0.12)(1.29,-0.64)(1.30,0.10)(1.31,-0.02)(1.32,-0.08)(1.33,0.46)(1.34,0.01)(1.35,0.37)(1.36,0.31)(1.37,-0.45)(1.38,0.89)(1.39,0.67)(1.40,0.52)(1.41,-0.45)(1.42,-0.17)(1.43,-0.28)(1.44,-0.16)(1.45,0.12)(1.46,0.23)(1.47,1.10)(1.48,-0.08)(1.49,0.39)(1.50,0.01)(1.51,-0.66)(1.52,0.28)(1.53,1.34)(1.54,-0.82)(1.55,-0.22)(1.56,0.52)(1.57,-0.42)(1.58,1.20)(1.59,-0.19)(1.60,0.13)(1.61,0.81)(1.62,-0.04)(1.63,1.63)(1.64,1.45)(1.65,0.01)(1.66,-0.35)(1.67,0.14)(1.68,-0.19)(1.69,0.07)(1.70,-0.81)(1.71,-0.15)(1.72,1.11)(1.73,0.23)(1.74,-0.28)(1.75,0.01)(1.76,0.13)(1.77,0.35)(1.78,-0.20)(1.79,0.03)(1.80,-1.14)(1.81,1.04)(1.82,0.11)(1.83,-0.03)(1.84,-0.49)(1.85,0.47)(1.86,0.40)(1.87,0.27)(1.88,-0.09)(1.89,-0.84)(1.90,-0.79)(1.91,-1.01)(1.92,-0.14)(1.93,0.18)(1.94,-0.07)(1.95,0.18)(1.96,-0.13)(1.97,-0.48)(1.98,-1.00)(1.99,-0.06)(2.00,-0.28)(2.01,0.37)(2.02,1.96)(2.03,-1.49)(2.04,0.07)(2.05,-1.21)(2.06,0.05)(2.07,0.11)(2.08,1.51)(2.09,0.01)(2.10,-0.48)(2.11,1.30)(2.12,0.06)(2.13,-0.02)(2.14,1.34)(2.15,0.19)(2.16,0.85)(2.17,0.49)(2.18,-0.11)(2.19,-1.82)(2.20,-1.11)(2.21,0.25)(2.22,-0.31)(2.23,0.22)(2.24,-0.80)(2.25,-0.31)(2.26,-0.46)(2.27,-0.02)(2.28,-1.48)(2.29,-1.16)(2.30,0.16)(2.31,0.04)(2.32,0.14)(2.33,1.52)(2.34,0.26)(2.35,0.05)(2.36,0.20)(2.37,-0.46)(2.38,-0.23)(2.39,0.40)(2.40,0.32)(2.41,0.27)(2.42,-0.58)(2.43,-0.90)(2.44,0.51)(2.45,0.05)(2.46,-0.80)(2.47,0.00)(2.48,-0.52)(2.49,-0.73)(2.50,-0.46)(2.51,0.01)(2.52,-0.41)(2.53,0.58)(2.54,0.02)(2.55,0.40)(2.56,-1.33)(2.57,-0.47)(2.58,1.55)(2.59,-0.26)(2.60,-0.33)(2.61,0.07)(2.62,-0.66)(2.63,0.71)(2.64,-0.43)(2.65,-0.39)(2.66,0.91)(2.67,0.43)(2.68,-0.05)(2.69,-0.19)(2.70,-0.08)(2.71,0.60)(2.72,-1.09)(2.73,-0.13)(2.74,0.08)(2.75,0.12)(2.76,0.43)(2.77,-0.70)(2.78,0.43)(2.79,1.15)(2.80,0.06)(2.81,0.04)(2.82,-0.61)(2.83,-0.49)(2.84,-0.41)(2.85,-0.50)(2.86,1.49)(2.87,0.72)(2.88,-0.26)(2.89,0.13)(2.90,-0.48)(2.91,-0.29)(2.92,-0.85)(2.93,0.52)(2.94,-0.22)(2.95,-0.21)(2.96,0.11)(2.97,-1.03)(2.98,0.12)(2.99,-1.35)(3.00,1.74)(3.01,-0.22)(3.02,0.12)(3.03,-0.02)(3.04,0.59)(3.05,1.37)(3.06,0.37)(3.07,0.61)(3.08,-0.44)(3.09,-0.15)(3.10,0.23)(3.11,0.90)(3.12,0.72)(3.13,0.22)(3.14,-0.06)(3.15,-0.28)(3.16,0.29)(3.17,0.30)(3.18,-0.48)(3.19,0.56)(3.20,0.62)(3.21,0.06)(3.22,0.01)(3.23,0.78)(3.24,-0.04)(3.25,0.11)(3.26,-0.24)(3.27,-0.01)(3.28,-0.27)(3.29,0.24)(3.30,0.44)(3.31,0.20)(3.32,0.19)(3.33,-0.63)(3.34,1.03)(3.35,-0.36)(3.36,-0.08)(3.37,-0.31)(3.38,0.43)(3.39,-1.73)(3.40,0.65)(3.41,0.09)(3.42,-1.14)(3.43,0.35)(3.44,0.46)(3.45,0.67)(3.46,-0.06)(3.47,-0.20)(3.48,-0.49)(3.49,0.26)(3.50,-0.73)(3.51,0.22)(3.52,-0.87)(3.53,-0.58)(3.54,0.04)(3.55,-0.59)(3.56,-0.34)(3.57,0.89)(3.58,-0.55)(3.59,0.67)(3.60,0.59)(3.61,0.06)(3.62,0.15)(3.63,-0.15)(3.64,0.99)(3.65,1.09)(3.66,-0.15)(3.67,-0.38)(3.68,1.26)(3.69,-0.20)(3.70,0.08)(3.71,-0.05)(3.72,0.16)(3.73,0.27)(3.74,0.22)(3.75,-0.08)(3.76,0.83)(3.77,0.84)(3.78,-1.15)(3.79,0.06)(3.80,0.51)(3.81,-0.30)(3.82,-0.92)(3.83,-0.34)(3.84,-0.03)(3.85,0.59)(3.86,-0.64)(3.87,1.01)(3.88,0.83)(3.89,0.05)(3.90,0.57)(3.91,1.75)(3.92,-0.28)(3.93,0.58)(3.94,0.02)(3.95,-0.55)(3.96,0.55)(3.97,-0.23)(3.98,-1.15)(3.99,0.21)(4.00,-0.53)(4.01,0.17)(4.02,-0.63)(4.03,-0.68)(4.04,0.33)(4.05,0.27)(4.06,-0.06)(4.07,0.43)(4.08,0.00)(4.09,-0.19)(4.10,0.43)(4.11,0.09)(4.12,-2.11)(4.13,0.16)(4.14,0.47)(4.15,-0.18)(4.16,-0.17)(4.17,-1.16)(4.18,-0.15)(4.19,1.09)(4.20,0.08)(4.21,-2.15)(4.22,0.40)(4.23,1.28)(4.24,0.04)(4.25,0.63)(4.26,0.90)(4.27,-0.71)(4.28,0.12)(4.29,-0.25)(4.30,-0.48)(4.31,0.65)(4.32,-0.10)(4.33,-0.57)(4.34,-0.02)(4.35,-0.20)(4.36,0.50)(4.37,0.15)(4.38,-0.43)(4.39,0.44)(4.40,-0.73)(4.41,-0.37)(4.42,0.28)(4.43,-0.07)(4.44,1.52)(4.45,-0.29)(4.46,-0.37)(4.47,-0.18)(4.48,-0.12)(4.49,1.06)(4.50,-0.48)(4.51,2.53)(4.52,-1.57)(4.53,0.09)(4.54,-0.76)(4.55,-0.36)(4.56,0.35)(4.57,-0.27)(4.58,-0.55)(4.59,-0.04)(4.60,0.43)(4.61,-0.14)(4.62,-0.28)(4.63,-0.20)(4.64,0.04)(4.65,0.46)(4.66,-0.84)(4.67,0.73)(4.68,-0.40)(4.69,-1.28)(4.70,-0.50)(4.71,0.59)(4.72,-0.30)(4.73,0.87)(4.74,1.47)(4.75,0.14)(4.76,0.75)(4.77,-0.85)(4.78,0.19)(4.79,0.51)(4.80,-0.60)(4.81,0.11)(4.82,-1.04)(4.83,0.26)(4.84,-0.00)(4.85,-0.11)(4.86,-1.06)(4.87,-0.95)(4.88,0.06)(4.89,-0.75)(4.90,0.52)(4.91,-0.33)(4.92,0.89)(4.93,0.86)(4.94,-0.06)(4.95,0.12)(4.96,-0.09)(4.97,0.80)(4.98,0.46)(4.99,0.37)(5.00,-0.27)(5.01,-1.24)(5.02,0.34)(5.03,0.46)(5.04,0.60)(5.05,0.41)(5.06,0.50)(5.07,0.46)(5.08,0.76)(5.09,-0.05)(5.10,1.43)(5.11,-0.10)(5.12,0.46)(5.13,-0.06)(5.14,0.97)(5.15,0.60)(5.16,-0.40)(5.17,1.44)(5.18,0.32)(5.19,-0.26)(5.20,-0.20)(5.21,-0.19)(5.22,0.55)(5.23,-0.78)(5.24,1.41)(5.25,-0.06)(5.26,1.90)(5.27,-0.15)(5.28,-0.26)(5.29,1.01)(5.30,-0.19)(5.31,-0.61)(5.32,-0.17)(5.33,0.01)(5.34,0.32)(5.35,0.09)(5.36,0.03)(5.37,-0.00)(5.38,-0.68)(5.39,-0.25)(5.40,0.19)(5.41,1.70)(5.42,-0.52)(5.43,0.38)(5.44,0.18)(5.45,-0.27)(5.46,-0.08)(5.47,-0.34)(5.48,-0.26)(5.49,-0.11)(5.50,0.29)(5.51,-0.03)(5.52,-0.87)(5.53,0.26)(5.54,0.16)(5.55,0.22)(5.56,0.52)(5.57,-0.36)(5.58,0.13)(5.59,0.41)(5.60,0.11)(5.61,-0.14)(5.62,0.32)(5.63,0.07)(5.64,-1.30)(5.65,0.84)(5.66,-1.17)(5.67,0.28)(5.68,-0.01)(5.69,0.35)(5.70,0.41)(5.71,-0.65)(5.72,0.06)(5.73,0.43)(5.74,0.19)(5.75,0.00)(5.76,1.39)(5.77,0.78)(5.78,0.24)(5.79,-0.60)(5.80,0.39)(5.81,-0.21)(5.82,-0.71)(5.83,0.56)(5.84,-0.15)(5.85,0.00)(5.86,-0.23)(5.87,0.31)(5.88,1.56)(5.89,0.11)(5.90,0.08)(5.91,-0.75)(5.92,0.28)(5.93,-0.65)(5.94,0.55)(5.95,0.03)(5.96,-0.29)(5.97,1.49)(5.98,-0.15)(5.99,0.41)(6.00,0.21)
      \end{pspicture}\label{fig_audio}}\hfill
    \subfloat[Anzahl der Kunden]{
      \setlength{\tempdim}{.4\linewidth/12}\psset{unit=\tempdim}
      \begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.5)(8,5)
        \psline{->}(0,5)
        \psline{->}(8,0)
        \uput[d](.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$9$}
        \uput[d](1.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$10$}
        \uput[d](2.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$11$}
        \uput[d](3.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$12$}
        \uput[d](4.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$13$}
        \uput[d](5.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$14$}
        \uput[d](6.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$15$}
        \uput[d](7.5,0.2){\tiny \strut$16$}
        \uput[l](0,.5){\tiny $1$}
        \uput[l](0,1){\tiny $2$}
        \uput[l](0,1.5){\tiny $3$}
        \uput[l](0,2){\tiny $4$}
        \uput[l](0,2.5){\tiny $5$}
        \uput[l](0,3){\tiny $6$}
        \uput[l](0,3.5){\tiny $7$}
        \uput[l](0,4){\tiny $8$}
        \uput[l](0,5){\tiny $x$}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](.5,0)(.5,2)\pscircle*(.5,2){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](1.5,0)(1.5,1)\pscircle*(1.5,1){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](2.5,0)(2.5,1)\pscircle*(2.5,1){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](3.5,0)(3.5,2.5)\pscircle*(3.5,2.5){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](4.5,0)(4.5,3.5)\pscircle*(4.5,3.5){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](5.5,0)(5.5,4)\pscircle*(5.5,4){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](6.5,0)(6.5,2.5)\pscircle*(6.5,2.5){.1}
        \psline[linewidth=0.2pt](7.5,0)(7.5,.5)\pscircle*(7.5,.5){.1}
      \end{pspicture}\label{fig_customer}}\hfill\\\hfill
    \subfloat[Frequenzantwort eines Bandpassfilters]{
      \setlength{\tempdim}{.4\linewidth/6}\psset{unit=\tempdim}
      \begin{pspicture}(-1,-0.5)(8,2)
        \psline{->}(0,2)
        \psline{->}(8,0)
        \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=.4pt,plotpoints=50,plotstyle=curve](0.00,0.00)(0.16,0.00)(0.33,0.00)(0.49,0.01)(0.65,0.01)(0.82,0.01)(0.98,0.02)(1.14,0.03)(1.31,0.04)(1.47,0.06)(1.63,0.09)(1.80,0.12)(1.96,0.18)(2.12,0.26)(2.29,0.38)(2.45,0.54)(2.61,0.76)(2.78,1.02)(2.94,1.31)(3.10,1.57)(3.27,1.76)(3.43,1.87)(3.59,1.94)(3.76,1.97)(3.92,1.98)(4.08,1.98)(4.24,1.97)(4.41,1.94)(4.57,1.87)(4.73,1.76)(4.90,1.57)(5.06,1.31)(5.22,1.02)(5.39,0.76)(5.55,0.54)(5.71,0.38)(5.88,0.26)(6.04,0.18)(6.20,0.12)(6.37,0.09)(6.53,0.06)(6.69,0.04)(6.86,0.03)(7.02,0.02)(7.18,0.01)(7.35,0.01)(7.51,0.01)(7.67,0.00)(7.84,0.00)(8.00,0.00)
        \uput[l](0,2){\tiny $\left|H(f)\right|$}
        \uput[d](8,0.1){\tiny \strut$f$}
        \uput[d](0,0.1){\tiny \strut$0$}
      \end{pspicture}\label{fig_passbandfilter}}\hfill
    \subfloat[Digitales Bild]{
      \setlength{\tempdim}{.4\linewidth/20}\psset{unit=\tempdim}
      \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(9,9)
        \uput[d](4.5,0){\tiny $\rightarrow$ $x$}
        \uput[l](0,3.5){\tiny $\uparrow$}
        \uput[l](0,4.5){\tiny $y$}
        \psframe*(2,8)(7,9)\psframe*(7,7)(8,8)\psframe*(8,2)(9,7)\psframe*(7,1)(8,2)\psframe*(2,0)(7,1)\psframe*(1,1)(2,2)\psframe*(0,2)(1,7)\psframe*(1,7)(2,8)
        \psframe*(2,6)(3,7)\psframe*(6,6)(7,7)
        \psframe*(4,4)(5,6)
        \psframe*(2,3)(3,4)\psframe*(3,2)(6,3)\psframe*(6,3)(7,4)
      \end{pspicture}\label{fig_picture}}\hfill\strut
    \caption{Unterschiedliche Signale}\label{fig_exasignals}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

compiles with `LaTeX -> DviPs -> ps2pdf`. In detail:

`LaTeX`:

[image: TeXnicCenter 1]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe`

Arguments: `--enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"`

`DviPs` (PDF):

[image: TeXnicCenter 2]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\dvips.exe`

Arguments: `-P pdf -R0 "%bm.dvi"`

and `Ghostscript` (`ps2pdf`):

[image: TeXnicCenter 3]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\mgs.exe`

Arguments: `-sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="%bm.pdf" -c save pop -f "%bm.ps"`

With this [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex) I adapted `TeXnicCenter` and the given document (added lines are commented out) for the use with `pdfLaTeX` (`LaTeX -> PDF`):

[image: TeXnicCenter 4]

Filepath: `D:\TeXnicCenter\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe`

Arguments: `--enable-write18 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm"`

However both possibilities from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8413/how-to-use-pstricks-in-pdflatex) it didn't compile on my machine. If I use `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}`, it leads to many

> Undefined control sequence.

errors. If I use `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, so it leads to a

> Command `\psfragfig` already defined.

error. Indeed in both cases I only added one of this two lines (`\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` or `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`) and let the preamble unchanged, because I don't exactly know, what can I remove/replace (with current stuff) and what should stay in any case.

What am I doing wrong? Every solution is welcome! **Please feel also free to clean up/change/modify/optimize the preamble!**

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: if you are using pstricks it really makes no sense to use pdflatex at all, you can do it in simple cases with auto-pst  but it is fragile and not recommended, use latex or lualatex. No document written this century should be loading `epsf` and `epsfig` packages, also the`\ifpdf`  test around hyperref is not recommended just load hyperref wihout `dvips` or `pdf` opion and let it choose the right thing.

Comment: Why should auto-pst-pdf be fragile?

Answer (score 0):

I will divide the project into two parts:

- a project (let's name it `diagrams.tex`) to produce PSTricks diagrams
- a project (let's name it `main.tex`) that uses the diagrams

In order to make consistent settings (mostly about fonts), I will create a package (let's name it `common.sty`) that contains common settings. This package will be imported by both projects.

For example:

### `diagrams.tex`

The following can be compiled with `lualatex` (recommended) or `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` (might fail due to recent issue) or `xelatex` (may fail).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{common}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-5,-5)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### `main.tex`

The following is compiled with `pdflatex` (recommended).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{common}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{others}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[page=...]{diagrams}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach is essentially the same as what the `auto-pst-pdf` package does, but the package creates the diagram files and the include code automatically.