# QR code for plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, qrcode

I am looking for a macro package for QR codes applicable in plain TeX. The QR code should be calculated from string at TeX macro level like in [qrcode.sty](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode), but this package is usable only for LaTeX.

I have found only solutions based on PostScript language or Lua language. But the same is doable using only TeX macro language as we seen in qrcode.sty.

Knows somebody about such macro package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you seen this answer here? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108735

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions work. wipets solution has more understandable source code and there are various options. But both solutions have an important disadvantage: they are not present at CTAN.

Comment: There also appears to be [this macroset](http://ktiml.mff.cuni.cz/~maj/QRcode.TeX).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did macros for QR code for plain TeX [qrcode.tex](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/makra/qrcode.tex). More precisely, I used the `qrcode.sty` by Andres Hendrickson and I removed all LaTeX specific things.

First of all, I asked the author if he remove LaTeX specific things himself because to make his macro independent of used format. But I received no response. Unfortunately, his macro is a mix of TeX primitives (`\vrule`, `\def`) or plain macros (`\newcount`) with LaTeX constructions (`\rule`, `\newcommand`, `\newcounter`). It was not trivial to remove the LaTeX dependencies, but it is done. The documentation is included in the mentioned file `qrcode.tex`.

Comment: That link appears to be gone. Could you upload the package to CTAN or elsewhere?

Comment: @FUZxxl Thank you for reporting. It is uploaded to CTAN already. See the package olsak-misc. And it is a part of TeXlive collection too.