# Define the color of a QR code

Tags: color, qrcode

I like the simple implementation for [QR codes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316722/89238) in Latex, for example:

```
\usepackage{qrcode}
```

...

```
\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}
```

But... is it possible to change the color?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like for other elements in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{blue}{\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}}
\end{document}
```

You even don't need to load `xcolor`, because `qrcode` already loads `xcolor` (without using it). But you can load it before `qrcode`, if you want to add options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{DarkBlue}{\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}}
\textcolor{Blue}{\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}}
\textcolor{LightBlue}{\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}}

\end{document}
```

[image: qrcode with different colors]

Note: The contrast of QR-Codes should be high. So the last one at the example above shouldn't be used!

This does work for all colors, e.g., a self defined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1.0,0.8,0.05,0.20}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{myblue}{\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}}

\end{document}
```

[image: with self defined color]

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for self-defined colors `\definecolor{myblue}{cmyk}{1.0,0.8,0.05,0.20}`

Comment: @API: Surely it does!

Comment: When using `hyperref` in conjuction with `colorlinks=true` and e.g. `urlcolor=[named]{blue}`, the `\textcolor{COLOR}{\qrcode{SOMETHING}}` command seems to ignore the `COLOR`.

Comment: Unfortunately as pointed out by @norok2, this is not working in combination with `hyperref`.

Comment: @norok2 @lumbric hyperref was not mentioned in the question. If you load package `hyperref` and the qrcodes should not be links, add package option `nolinks`: `\usepackage[nolinks]{qrcode}`. You can also use option `nolink` for `\qrcode`: `\qrcode[nolink]{SOMETHING}` or the starred version `\qrcode*`: `\qrcode*{SOMETHING}`.

Comment: @norok2 @lumbric If the qrcode should be a link using the color given by `\textcolor`: `\textcolor{COLOR}{\hypersetup{urlcolor=.}\qrcode{SOMETHING}}`. But then to have to ensure that `\hypersetup` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following Setup worked:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     linkcolor    = NavyBlue,
     urlcolor     = NavyBlue,
     citecolor    = NavyBlue,
     filecolor    = NavyBlue,
}

\usepackage{qrcode}
```

Apparently, `filecolor` was the one changing the color of the QR code itself. I prefer NavyBlue, but you could choose any color you like. In this case, using \textcolor does not work and is overwritten by the color options defined on `\hypersetup`.