# QR code in ConTeXt

Tags: graphics, context, qrcode

In LaTeX there is a the [qrcode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/latex-package-to-generate-qr-codes) package. Is there any way to create a qrcode in ConTeXt?

Something like this:

```
\qr[1in]{Your text to be QR encoded here}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first attempt. We can generate a MetaPost graphic if we want, but this seems faster and easier to do. With some more commands, we can even write a small module, in case anyone else needs it. You only need `qrencode.lua` from [here](https://github.com/speedata/luaqrcode) (the other files are prescindible).

**EDIT**: My first solution only worked with ConTeXt LMTX. The following one should work both with MkIV and LMTX. At this point it's better to moving to the latter, though.

```
\startluacode

local table      = table 
local concat     = table.concat

local interfaces = interfaces
local implement  = interfaces.implement

local qr = require"qrencode"

local function helper(n)
    if n > 0  then return 0      end
    if n < 0  then return 2^24-1 end
    if n == 0 then return 2^12   end --Should it happen?
end

local function qrcode_to_ctx(size, text)
    local n, data, settings
    local ok, content = qr.qrcode(text)
    local result = ''

    if not ok then
        context.type(content) 
    else
        data     = {}
        n        = #content
        settings = {
            x      = n, 
            y      = n,
            width  = size,
            height = size
        }    
        for i = 1, n do
            data[i] = {}
            for j = 1, n do
                data[i][j] = ('%06X'):format(helper(content[i][j]))
            end
            result = result .. concat(data[i])
        end
        context.bitmapimage(settings,result)
    end
end

implement{
    name      = 'qrcode',
    arguments = {'string', 'string'},
    actions   = qrcode_to_ctx
}

\stopluacode
\unprotect
\unexpanded\def\qrcode{\dosingleempty\qrcode_direct}
\def\qrcode_direct[#1]#2%
    {\quitvmode\doifsomethingelse{#1}%
     {\clf_qrcode{#1}{#2}}
     {\clf_qrcode{1cm}{#2}}} %Change 1cm for another default
\protect
\starttext
\startTEXpage
\qrcode[5cm]{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598634/qr-code-in-context}
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Jairo, perhaps you could include it as a package to context distro for "use and enjoyment" of other people.

Comment: @somenxavier Hans has uploaded a module which depends on an external program, but it's faster (`m-zint`). I'll share Hans' method ASAP, but in the meantime I could provide this alternative as a separate module :)

Comment: Jairo, I recommend you upload this as module, because as you said `m-zint` depends on external program. Your implementation is clean

Comment: I get `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/l-sandbox.lua:180: module 'qrencode' not found:`

Comment: @somenxavier You need to download `qrencode` from the link I provided. There are two ways: (1) put it in `/usr/share/texmf-modules` (it should exist) and run in order `mtxrun --generate`, `context --make` from the command line or (2) put in the same folder as your main file